# How do you display a Toast from a background thread on Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-toast

How can I display [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) messages from a thread?

Answer (score 263, accepted):

You can do it by calling an `Activity`'s `runOnUiThread` method from your thread:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to do this. I have my existing public void run(). I tried putting this code there. I know that's not right because it didn't work, but I am really stuck.

Comment: Is "activity" passed to the non-ui-thread in its constructor?  What is the right way to get the activity object that you are using from within the separate thread?

Comment: Set the `Thread` object's reference to the `Activity` in the `Activity`'s `onResume`. Unset it in the `Activity`'s `onPause`. Do both under a `synchronized` lock that both the `Activity` and `Thread` respect.

Comment: sometimes there is no access to ```Activity``` instance, you can use simple helper-class instead, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18280318/1891118

Comment: I've usually found that `MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread()` works just fine from within an inner `Thread`/`AsyncTask`.

Comment: `runOnUiThread` does not seem to be available in the newer version of android api.

Answer (score 72):

I like to have a method in my activity called `showToast` which I can call from anywhere...

```
public void showToast(final String toast)
{
    runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
}
```

I then most frequently call it from within `MyActivity` on any thread like this...

```
showToast(getString(R.string.MyMessage));
```

Comment: For TOAST, always use Application Context, not Activity Context!

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub why?

Comment: @OneWorld, proofs: 1- For a toast message, the Google Dev Guide uses the application context and explicitly say's to use it. 2- http://stackoverflow.com/a/4128799/1429432 3- http://stackoverflow.com/a/10347346/1429432 4- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/3i8M6-wAIwM/EQOdAZKxsQYJ

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub 
 
There is a lot of discussion and guessing in the links you provided. E.g. RomainGuy says there is no memory leak in your proof no. 4. Some of the links are from the early days of Android in 2009. Also people say in the other links that you can use both contexts. Activity and application. Maybe you have a more up to date real evidence based proof? Do you have a link for 1?

Comment: 1- outdated? lol dude they wont be updated, and you CANT find any updated article in this case. So follow the old(?) rules if you dont have any idea or cant prove it.

Comment: If Google suggested us to use ApplicationContext, then they should make it easier to access it, and stop returning null in any case. e.g. fragment.getApplicationContext().

Answer (score 34):

This is similar to other answers, however updated for new available apis and much cleaner.  Also, does not assume you're in an Activity Context.

```
public class MyService extends AnyContextSubclass {

    public void postToastMessage(final String message) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: When the context you have is not an activity that is the perfect answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 26):

One approach that works from pretty much anywhere, including from places where you don't have an `Activity` or `View`, is to grab a `Handler` to the main thread and show the toast:

```
public void toast(final Context context, final String text) {
  Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
  handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  });
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it works with any `Context`, including `Service` and `Application`.

Comment: What if your app is backgrounded, and a service thread calls this code, will the toast display when the app is foregrounded? I'm curios what happens to the main application thread when the app backgrounded. Does it pause, and not execute tasks in the event loop? And then resume?

Answer (score 10):

Like [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) or [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)), with a `Runnable` that shows the `Toast`.
Namely,

```
Activity activity = // reference to an Activity
// or
View view = // reference to a View

activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        showToast(activity);
    }
});
// or
view.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        showToast(view.getContext());
    }
});

private void showToast(Context ctx) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Hi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, you have to send message from another `Thread` to UI thread. This type of scenario occurs when you can't execute Network/IO operations on UI thread.

Below example handles that scenario.

1. You have UI Thread
2. You have to start IO operation and hence you can't run `Runnable` on UI thread. So post your `Runnable` to handler on `HandlerThread`
3. Get the result from `Runnable` and send it back to UI thread and show a `Toast` message.

Solution:

1. Create a [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) and start it
2. Create a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) with [Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) from `HandlerThread`:`requestHandler`
3. Create a Handler with Looper from Main Thread:  `responseHandler` and override `handleMessage` method
4. `post` a `Runnable` task on `requestHandler`
5. Inside `Runnable` task, call `sendMessage` on `responseHandler`
6. This `sendMessage` result invocation of `handleMessage` in `responseHandler`.
7. Get attributes from the `Message` and process it, update UI

Sample code:

```
    /* Handler thread */

    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
    handlerThread.start();
    Handler requestHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());

    final Handler responseHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //txtView.setText((String) msg.obj);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Runnable on HandlerThread is completed and got result:"+(String)msg.obj,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    };

    for ( int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    /* Add your business logic here and construct the 
                       Messgae which should be handled in UI thread. For 
                       example sake, just sending a simple Text here*/

                    String text = "" + (++rId);
                    Message msg = new Message();

                    msg.obj = text.toString();
                    responseHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    System.out.println(text.toString());

                } catch (Exception err) {
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        requestHandler.post(myRunnable);
    }
```

Useful articles:

[handlerthreads-and-why-you-should-be-using-them-in-your-android-apps](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/handlerthreads-and-why-you-should-be-using-them-in-your-android-apps-dc8bf1540341)

[android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i](https://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/)

Answer (score 5):

1. Get UI Thread Handler instance and use `handler.sendMessage();`
2. Call `post()` method `handler.post();`
3. `runOnUiThread()`
4. `view.post()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Looper` to send `Toast` message.  Go through this  [link](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.kr/2013/09/android-looper-and-toast-from.html) for more details.

```
public void showToastInThread(final Context context,final String str){
    Looper.prepare();
    MessageQueue queue = Looper.myQueue();
    queue.addIdleHandler(new IdleHandler() {
         int mReqCount = 0;

         @Override
         public boolean queueIdle() {
             if (++mReqCount == 2) {
                  Looper.myLooper().quit();
                  return false;
             } else
                  return true;
         }
    });
    Toast.makeText(context, str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
    Looper.loop();
}
```

and it is called in your thread. Context may be `Activity.getContext()` getting from the `Activity` you have to show the toast.

Answer (score 2):

I made this approach based on mjaggard answer:

```
public static void toastAnywhere(final String text) {
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(SuperApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), text, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin Code with runOnUiThread**

```
runOnUiThread(
        object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Calling from runOnUiThread()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)  
            }
        }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem:

```text
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
              Process: com.example.languoguang.welcomeapp, PID: 4724
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:393)
                  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:117)
                  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:280)
                  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:270)
                  at com.example.languoguang.welcomeapp.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:51)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4724 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Before: onCreate function

```java
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Thread", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
thread.start();
```

After: onCreate function

```java
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Thread", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

it worked.

Answer (score 0):

java 11:

```
var handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper);
handler.post(() -> Toast.makeText(your_context, "Hi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
```

Lambdas are available in java 8 though. `var` is introduced in java 11.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to almost every answer here, `Toast#makeText` and `Toast#show` do **NOT** have to run on the UI thread. The *only* requirement is that it runs on a thread that has called `Looper#prepare`.

The reasons for this is because toasts are handled and rendered by the OS, not the application. Internally, `Toast#show` makes a call to a system service to enqueue the toast.

This means the following code is valid

```java
private static class MyThread extends Thread {
    public Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        handler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper()) {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        };

        Looper.loop()
    }
}

final private MyThread t = new MyThread();
// start and wait for t to start looping

private void onClick() {
    t.handler.post(() -> Toast.makeText(this, "this works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method in onCreate :**

```
private void toastPublic(final String message){
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+message, 
             4 /*Toast.LENGTH_SHORT*/).show();
    }});
}
```

**Next : use in inside Thread**