# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, ui-thread, android-toast

What does the following exception mean; how can I fix it?

This is the code:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

This is the exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
```

Comment: check this library `compile 'com.shamanland:xdroid-toaster:0.0.5'`, it doesn't require `runOnUiThread()` or `Context` variable, all routine is gone! just invoke `Toaster.toast(R.string.my_msg);` here is the example: https://github.com/shamanland/xdroid-toaster-example

Comment: What a stupid error message! It could've been as simple as - can't call this from a non-UI thread as done when views are touched from a non-UI thread.

Comment: For those who get the same exception message from different code: What the exception message means is that you are calling the code via a thread that has not prepared Looper. Normally it means you are not calling if from UI thread but you should (OP's case) - a normal thread does not prepare Looper, but UI thread always do.

Comment: @OleksiiKropachov the implementation of the library you mentioned is very similar to doing a runOnUiThread().

Comment: yes, but it's a very useful wrapper

Comment: @DheerajBhaskar I wouldn't judge an expert developer's decision so quickly, it is stupid when you're not aware of the other scenarios this exception also covers, for me I had the same exception unrelated to the UI-Thread, the IABHandler that was given out by google itself for reference to use for in app purchase, was using new Handler without having Looper.getMainLooper(), for some "stupid" reasons ;) when I was using it normally I didn't have any problem, but when I used it inside an Executors thread pool, I got the same exception, never used any UI related method in there

Answer (score 840, accepted):

You're calling it from a worker thread. You need to call `Toast.makeText()` (and most other functions dealing with the UI) from within the main thread. You could use a handler, for example.

Look up [Communicating with the UI Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) in the documentation. In a nutshell:

```
// Set this up in the UI thread.

mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        // This is where you do your work in the UI thread.
        // Your worker tells you in the message what to do.
    }
};

void workerThread() {
    // And this is how you call it from the worker thread:
    Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage(command, parameter);
    message.sendToTarget();
}
```

**Other options:**

You could use [`Activity.runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)). Straightforward if you have an `Activity`:

```java
@WorkerThread
void workerThread() {
    myActivity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
        // This is where your UI code goes.
    }
}
```

You could also post to the main looper. This works great if all you have is a `Context`.

```java
@WorkerThread
void workerThread() {
    ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context).execute(()  -> {
        // This is where your UI code goes.
    }
}
```

**Deprecated:**

You could use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), that works well for most things running in the background. It has hooks that you can call to indicate the progress, and when it's done.

It's convenient, but can leak contexts if not used correctly. It's been officially deprecated, and you shouldn't use it anymore.

Comment: what about the original problem (it wasn't about AlertDialog)?

Comment: Just adding my two cents to what Cleggy said. It would be preferable to provide a brief demonstration of what you mean (however contrived), as a coded example can often speak volumes for itself.

Comment: for a full technical answer see this http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.kr/2013/09/android-looper-and-toast-from.html

Comment: In almost all programming languages AFAIK which support GUI, if you update/change/display/interact with GUI directly, it should be done on the main thread of the program.

Comment: `(and most other functions dealing with the UI)` An example of a UI function usable from the background is `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar` -- its functionality is undiminished when not calling from the UI thread.

Comment: this answer is not much useful bit complicated

Comment: I wish the code was completed so I could see a full example.

Comment: I had a similar use case.  "ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context).execute(()  -> { ..." did the trick.

Answer (score 987):

You need to call `Toast.makeText(...)` from the UI thread:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

This is copy-pasted from [another (duplicate) SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3134683/110358).

Comment: Great answer. This had me confused for a while. Just to note, I did not need the activity. before runOnUiThread.

Comment: @Cen92 actually you need >_<. runOnUiThread is a method of activity.

Comment: It worked with out "activity" and in the toast I have used MainActivity.this  What is >_< ?

Answer (score 462):

### **UPDATE - 2016**

The best alternative is to use `RxAndroid` (specific bindings for `RxJava`) for the `P` in `MVP` to take charge fo data.

Start by returning `Observable` from your existing method.

```
private Observable<PojoObject> getObservableItems() {
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {

        for (PojoObject pojoObject: pojoObjects) {
            subscriber.onNext(pojoObject);
        }
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    });
}
```

Use this Observable like this -

```
getObservableItems().
subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
subscribe(new Observer<PojoObject> () {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        // Print Toast on completion
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {}

    @Override
    public void onNext(PojoObject pojoObject) {
        // Show Progress
    }
});
}
```

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I know I am a little late but here goes.
Android basically works on two thread types namely **UI thread** and **background thread**. According to android documentation -

> Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread to fix this problem, Android offers several ways to access the UI thread from other threads. Here is a list of methods that can help:

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)  
View.post(Runnable)  
View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)
```

Now there are various methods to solve this problem.

I will explain it by code sample:

## runOnUiThread

```
new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        myactivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                //Do your UI operations like dialog opening or Toast here
            }
        });
    }
}.start();
```

### LOOPER

> Class used to run a message loop for a thread. Threads by default do
>   not have a message loop associated with them; to create one, call
>   prepare() in the thread that is to run the loop, and then loop() to
>   have it process messages until the loop is stopped.

```
class LooperThread extends Thread {
    public Handler mHandler;

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        mHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // process incoming messages here
            }
        };

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

### AsyncTask

> AsyncTask allows you to perform asynchronous work on your user
>   interface. It performs the blocking operations in a worker thread and
>   then publishes the results on the UI thread, without requiring you to
>   handle threads and/or handlers yourself.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new CustomTask().execute((Void[])null);
}


private class CustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {
        //Do some work
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
        //Print Toast or open dialog
    }
}
```

### Handler

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects
>   associated with a thread's MessageQueue.

```
Message msg = new Message();


new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        msg.arg1=1;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}.start();



Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.arg1==1)
        {
            //Print Toast or open dialog        
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for. Especially the first example with `runOnUiThread`

Comment: Thanks, 5 years of Android programming and I never knew `View` also has methods `post(Runnable)` and `postDelayed(Runnable, long)`! So many Handlers in vain. :)

Comment: for those who are confused by the Handler example: what is the thread that "new Handler(callback)" is bind to? It's bound to the thread that created the handler.

Comment: Why is this **the best alternative**?

Comment: I usw doInBackground and I want to get a ArrayList back but I always get the error: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare(). See this is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562615/looper-prepare-error-from-asyncthread-doinbackground?noredirect=1#comment78084303_45562615 but I can't get the solution from this answer here

Comment: Years later, this was what I was looking for. Thank you.

observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).

Comment: This is elegant to show the toast in different ways in non UI Thread @mjosh

Comment: Instead of  Print Toast or open dialog  can I open a form or activity?

Comment: My only regret is that I have but only one "up" vote to give.. +1000

Answer (score 234):

`Toast.makeText()` can only be called from Main/UI thread. [Looper.getMainLooper()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper()) helps you to achieve it:

**JAVA**

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // write your code here
    }
});
```

**KOTLIN**

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
        // write your code here
}
```

An advantage of this method is that you can run UI code without Activity or Context.

Comment: Thanks the other answers werent working for me. I am using a library sugar record to manage the persistence. And inside it i dont have the activity. But this works wonderfully

Comment: @AyazAlifov You say "it doesn't require Context", so what is mContext refering to?

Comment: Hi @akhilnair. Context is not required in order to run the android code by Main/UI thread. Main/UI thread can contain any code. In this specific example there is Toast method, which needs Context by its implementation.

Answer (score 99):

Try this, when you see runtimeException due to Looper not prepared before handler.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); 

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
  // Run your task here
  }
}, 1000 );
```

Comment: Handler is an abstract classs. this doesn't compile

Comment: @StealthRabbi import Handler from correct namespace i.e. `android.os.Handler`

Comment: This may not be the issue.  A looper may not exist from the calling class, period.

Answer (score 44):

I ran into the same problem, and here is how I fixed it:

```
private final class UIHandler extends Handler
{
    public static final int DISPLAY_UI_TOAST = 0;
    public static final int DISPLAY_UI_DIALOG = 1;

    public UIHandler(Looper looper)
    {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch(msg.what)
        {
        case UIHandler.DISPLAY_UI_TOAST:
        {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, (String)msg.obj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
        }
        case UIHandler.DISPLAY_UI_DIALOG:
            //TBD
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

protected void handleUIRequest(String message)
{
    Message msg = uiHandler.obtainMessage(UIHandler.DISPLAY_UI_TOAST);
    msg.obj = message;
    uiHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

To create the UIHandler, you'll need to perform the following:

```
    HandlerThread uiThread = new HandlerThread("UIHandler");
    uiThread.start();
    uiHandler = new UIHandler((HandlerThread) uiThread.getLooper());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried to use your code but i lost and not sure how to call from `onCreate method` or from AsyncTask in my situation will you please post the entire code just to learn how things work?

Comment: Shouldn't that final line read

`uiHandler = new UIHandler(uiThread.getLooper());`

?

Answer (score 40):

**Reason for an error:**

Worker threads are meant for doing background tasks and you can't show anything on UI within a worker thread unless you call method like **runOnUiThread**. If you try to show anything on UI thread without calling runOnUiThread, there will be a `java.lang.RuntimeException`.

So, if you are in an `activity` but calling `Toast.makeText()` from worker thread, do this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{
   public void run() 
   {
      Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
   }
});
```

The above code ensures that you are showing the Toast message in a `UI thread` since you are calling it inside `runOnUiThread` method. So no more `java.lang.RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 24):

that's what i did.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast(...);
    }
});
```

Visual components are "locked" to changes from outside threads.
So, since the toast shows stuff on the main screen that is managed by the main thread, you need to run this code on that thread.
Hope that helps:)

Comment: I used this same method. However, does this leave open the possibility of leaks, because the anonymous inner class of the Runnable will hold an implicit reference to the Activity?

Comment: That's a fine point:) just use getApplicationContext() or something like that, to be on the safe side. altough i never had any problems with that code that i know of

Answer (score 22):

I was getting this error until I did the following.

```
public void somethingHappened(final Context context)
{
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(
        new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Something happened.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

And made this into a singleton class:

```
public enum Toaster {
    INSTANCE;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    public void postMessage(final String message) {
        handler.post(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(ApplicationHolder.INSTANCE.getCustomApplication(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                }
            }
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you using **Toaster**?  In your first snippet it isn't used...

Comment: it was a convenience class I used like `Toaster.INSTANCE.postMessage(ResourceUtils.getString(R.string.blah));` (lengthy I know! we reduced this later), although I haven't been using toasts in a while

Comment: So what does `ApplicationHolder.INSTANCE` evaluate to?

Comment: A static variable of `CustomApplication` set in `CustomApplication.onCreate()`, considering application always exists while the process exists, this context can be used globally

Answer (score 15):

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: This worked for me and I use lambda `runOnUiThread(() -> {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        });`

Answer (score 15):

Wonderful Kotlin solution:

```
runOnUiThread {
    // Add your ui thread code here
}
```

Comment: `runOnUiThread` is a part of Activity i.e.
`activity?.runOnUiThread {
            ...
        }`

Answer (score 14):

first call `Looper.prepare()` and then call `Toast.makeText().show()` last call `Looper.loop()` like:

```
Looper.prepare() // to be able to make toast
Toast.makeText(context, "not connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
Looper.loop()
```

Comment: Why this answer is underrated ?

Comment: I don't know about the current usage, but this saved me while using a jar file in a runnable that contained an activity internally.

Answer (score 11):

This is because Toast.makeText() is calling from a worker thread. It should be call from main UI thread like this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 8):

The answer by ChicoBird worked for me. The only change I made was in the creation of the UIHandler where I had to do

```
HandlerThread uiThread = new HandlerThread("UIHandler");
```

Eclipse refused to accept anything else. Makes sense I suppose.

Also the `uiHandler` is clearly a class global defined somewhere. I still don't claim to understand how Android is doing this and what is going on but I am glad it works. Now I will proceed to study it and see if I can understand what Android is doing and why one has to go through all these hoops and loops. Thanks for the help ChicoBird.

Answer (score 6):

Coroutine will do it perfectly

```
CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "yourmessage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}
```

Answer (score 5):

For Rxjava and RxAndroid User:

```
public static void shortToast(String msg) {
    Observable.just(msg)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(message -> {
                Toast.makeText(App.getInstance(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
}
```

Comment: Those brackets are unnecessary

Answer (score 5):

### Java 8

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
    // Work in the UI thread

});
```

### Kotlin

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post{
    // Work in the UI thread
}
```

GL

Answer (score 4):

I was running into the same issue when my callbacks would try to show a dialog.

I solved it with dedicated methods in the Activity - at the Activity *instance member level* - that use `runOnUiThread(..)`

```
public void showAuthProgressDialog() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mAuthProgressDialog = DialogUtil.getVisibleProgressDialog(SignInActivity.this, "Loading ...");
        }
    });
}

public void dismissAuthProgressDialog() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mAuthProgressDialog == null || ! mAuthProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                return;
            }
            mAuthProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Handler handler2;  
HandlerThread handlerThread=new HandlerThread("second_thread");
handlerThread.start();
handler2=new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
```

Now handler2 will use a different Thread to handle the messages than the main Thread.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and this code is working fine for me now.
As an example this is my code to do a task in the background and UI thread.
Observe how the looper is used:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();
                                
    // your Background Task here

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        // update your UI here      
                                
        Looper.loop();
        }
    });
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

To display a dialog or a toaster in a thread, the most concise way is to use the Activity object.

For example:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                myActivity.this.processingWaitDialog = new ProgressDialog(myActivity.this.getContext());
                myActivity.this.processingWaitDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                myActivity.this.processingWaitDialog.setMessage("abc");
                myActivity.this.processingWaitDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                myActivity.this.processingWaitDialog.show();
            }
        });
        expenseClassify.serverPost(
                new AsyncOperationCallback() {
                    public void operationCompleted(Object sender) {
                        myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                if (myActivity.this.processingWaitDialog != null 
                                        && myActivity.this.processingWaitDialog.isShowing()) {
                                    myActivity.this.processingWaitDialog.dismiss();
                                    myActivity.this.processingWaitDialog = null;
                                }
                            }
                        }); // .runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lambda:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Toast, AlertDialogs** needs to run on UI thread, you can use **Asynctask** to use them properly in android development.but some cases we need to customize the time outs, so we use **Threads**, but in threads we cannot use Toast,Alertdialogs like we using in AsyncTask.So we need separate **Handler**  for popup those.

```
public void onSigned() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                sleep(3000);
                Message message = new Message();
                message.what = 2;
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

in Above example i want to sleep my thread in 3sec and after i want to show a Toast message,for that in your **mainthread** implement handler.

```
handler = new Handler() {
       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
           switch(msg.what){
              case 1:
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"cool",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              break;
           }
           super.handleMessage(msg);
       }
};
```

I used switch case here, because if you need to show different message in same way, you can use switch case within Handler class...hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when something on the main thread is called from any background thread. Lets look at an example , for instance.

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        textView.setText("Any Text");
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the above example , we are setting text on the textview which is in the main UI thread from doInBackground() method , which operates only on a worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it simply by putting the Toast in onPostExecute() override function of the Asynctask<> and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create toast on UI thread. Find the example below.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "YOUR_MESSAGE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

For displaying Toast message please refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@codingwithdarshana/android-toast-c73628962ede)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for Kotlin using Coroutine:

Extend your class with CoroutineScope by MainScope():

```
class BootstrapActivity :  CoroutineScope by MainScope() {}
```

Then simply do this:

```
launch {
        // whatever you want to do in the main thread
    }
```

Don't forget to add the dependencies for coroutine:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:${Versions.kotlinCoroutines}
org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:${Versions.kotlinCoroutines}
```

Comment: Or simply `launch(Dispatchers.Main) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Create Handler outside the Thread

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            try{
                 handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            showAlertDialog(p.getProviderName(), Token, p.getProviderId(), Amount);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("ProvidersNullExp", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I encounter this problem - It was happening because I was trying to call a function that was to do some UI stuff from the constructor. Removing the initialization from the constructor solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -2):

i use the following code to show message from non main thread "context",

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface IShowMessage {
    Context getContext();

    default void showMessage(String message) {
        final Thread mThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Looper.loop();
                } catch (Exception error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("IShowMessage", error.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };
        mThread.start();
    }
}
```

then use as the following:

```
class myClass implements IShowMessage{

  showMessage("your message!");
 @Override
    public Context getContext() {
        return getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```