# Update UI from Thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I want to update my UI from a Thread which updates a Progressbar. Unfortunately, when updating the progressbar's drawable from the "runnable" the progressbar disappears! 
Changing the progressbars's drawable in `onCreate()` on the otherside works!

Any Suggestions?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    res = getResources();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gameone);
    pB.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green)); //**Works**/
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1);       
}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {  
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() 
            { 
                //* The Complete ProgressBar does not appear**/                         
                pB.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green)); 
            } 
        }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 64):

You should do this with the help of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (an intelligent backround thread) and [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html), as explained in the [docs](http://web.archive.org/web/20091203105247/http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
> allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
> thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
>
> An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a
> background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread. An
> asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params,
> Progress and Result, and 4 steps, called begin, doInBackground,
> processProgress and end.
>
> **The 4 steps**
>
> When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:
>
> `onPreExecute()`, invoked on the UI thread immediately after the task
> is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for
> instance by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
>
> `doInBackground(Params...)`, invoked on the background thread
> immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
> to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
> parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
> result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
> passed back to the last step. This step can also use
> publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
> These values are published on the UI thread, in the
> onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
>
> `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)`, invoked on the UI thread after a call
> to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
> undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
> user interface while the background computation is still executing.
> For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
> a text field.
>
> `onPostExecute(Result)`, invoked on the UI thread after the background
> computation finishes. The result of the background computation is
> passed to this step as a parameter. Threading rules
>
> **There are a few threading rules that must be followed for this class to work properly:**
>
> The task instance must be created on the UI thread. execute(Params...)
> must be invoked on the UI thread. Do not call onPreExecute(),
> onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...),
> onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually. The task can be executed only
> once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

**Example code**   What the adapter does in this example is not important, more important to understand that you need to use AsyncTask to display a dialog for the progress.

```
private class PrepareAdapter1 extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ContactsListCursorAdapter > {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(viewContacts.this);
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait_while_loading));
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
     */
    @Override
    protected ContactsListCursorAdapter doInBackground(Void... params) {
        cur1 = objItem.getContacts();
        startManagingCursor(cur1);

        adapter1 = new ContactsListCursorAdapter (viewContacts.this,
                R.layout.contact_for_listitem, cur1, new String[] {}, new int[] {});

        return adapter1;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ContactsListCursorAdapter result) {
        list.setAdapter(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: "AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) [...]" - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 26):

The most simplest solution I have seen to supply a short 
execution to the UI thread is via the post() method of a view.
This is needed since UI methods are not re-entrant. The
method for this is:

```
package android.view;

public class View;

public boolean post(Runnable action);
```

The post() method corresponds to the SwingUtilities.invokeLater().
Unfortunately I didn't find something simple that corresponds to 
the SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(), but one can build the later
based on the former with a monitor and a flag.

So what you save by this is creating a handler. You simply need
to find your view and then post on it. You can find your view via 
findViewById() if you tend to work with id-ed resources. The resulting
code is very simple:

```
/* inside your non-UI thread */

view.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            /* the desired UI update */
        }
    });
}
```

Note: Compared to SwingUtilities.invokeLater() the method 
View.post() does return a boolean, indicating whether the 
view has an associated event queue. Since I used the 
invokeLater() resp. post() anyway only for fire and forget, 
I did not check the result value. Basically you should 
call post() only after onAttachedToWindow() has been called 
on the view.

Best Regards

Comment: If the `view` is a reference to an actual object like `progress bar`, leaving an activity or fragment which creates the whole view would recycle the `view` resource, causing `null`.post(~);

Comment: For how to kill the looper via a post see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30562809/502187

Answer (score 10):

Use the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class (instead of Runnable). It has a method called onProgressUpdate which can affect the UI (it's invoked in the UI thread).

Answer (score 10):

If you use `Handler` (I see you do and hopefully you created its instance on the UI thread), then don't use `runOnUiThread()` inside of your `runnable`. `runOnUiThread()` is used when you do smth from a non-UI thread, however `Handler` will already execute your `runnable` on UI thread.

Try to do smth like this:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gameone);
    res = getResources();
    // pB.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green)); **//Works**
    mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1);
}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        pB.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green));
        pB.invalidate(); // maybe this will even not needed - try to comment out
    }
};
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to create a `Handler` in the UI thread and then use it to post or send a message from your other thread to update the UI

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the AsyncTask you could use the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  In that example use the ResponseHandler as an inner class in your activity then have a string message that will set the progress bars percentage...  You would need to make sure that any alterations to the UI are performed within the ResponseHandler to avoid freezing up the UI, then your worker thread (EventSource in the example) can perform the tasks required.

I would use the AsyncTask tho, however the observer pattern can be good for customization reasons, plus its easier to understand.  Also im not sure if this way is widely accepted or will 100% work.  Im downloading and the android plugin now to test it

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads.html), you can use  [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) ***to handle work items shorter than 5ms in duration***. If your task take more time, lookout for other alternatives.

[HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html)  is one alternative to `Thread` or `AsyncTask`. If you need to update UI from `HandlerThread`, post a message on UI Thread `Looper` and UI Thread [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) can handle UI updates.

Example code:

[Android: Toast in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread/45922317#45922317)