# Update UI from another thread (progressDialog)

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, progressdialog

I searched and found what looked like the exact question I have (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369537/update-ui-from-thread).  Unfortunately I'm still not able to get this working.

I have an ImageView on my layout.  When a button is pressed, a ProgressDialog is created and shown.  As the thread processes data, it calls the incrementProgressBy() method on a handler in the UI.  Inside that handler, I update the ImageView using setImageBitmap(), and then I Invalidate it.  It never updates.  Next, I tried calling ImageView.postInvalidate() from the progress bar's thread.  It still does not update until the progress bar completes and is removed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you're doing it correctly as far as the handler.  It's not necessary to invalidate the bitmap since setImageBitmap() does that already.

Comment: You should post your code. Also you know when you display a ProgressDialog your activity is paused. Maybe that's the reason? Can you try all the same without ProgressDialog.

Comment: I really can't go without the dialog.  Essentially, the user takes photos with the application and enters information.  These photos are uploaded to a web service later.  The progress bar indicates how many photos have gone and how many are left.  Since the progress dialog does not cover the whole screen I thought it would be nice to display the image being sent in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here was to use an AsyncTask.  It's able to communicate with the UI via handlers.