# I am trying to make a simple thread that changes a textview after a time

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, ui-thread

The problem is that when i click the button for the second my application crashes and i don't understand why. When i clink the button for the second time is suppose to the same all over again.

Any help is appreciated.

```
public class main extends Activity {

    Boolean grabar = false;

    TextView texto;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto);
        Button startbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        startbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){

                    background.start();
            }
           });
    }

    Thread background = new Thread (new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

                    try {

                                         Thread.sleep(3000);
                        cambiarHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }  

     });

    Handler cambiarHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {             

           texto.setText("ok");  

        }
    };


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem I see is that threads are designed to run once. You need to create a new instance of the thread each time you wish to run it.

Comment: If you attempt to start a thread that has already ran, it will throw an error you need to put the entire thread (instantiation and all) in the button. I'm not going to go into if this is a good or bad idea, just saying thats how to make it work

Comment: ok it work at first but now i added some new things and after all is done i click the button and the application just exit. any ideas?? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This may well have something to do with Android's policy of only allowing the UI thread to modify the UI.

You should be using ASyncTask instead if you want to modify the UI from a separate thread.

See here:

[Update UI from Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369537/update-ui-from-thread/4370785#4370785)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which exception is thrown. I guess it is NPE thrown. When you try to set text to the `TextView`. Try instantiating the `TextView` within the `handleMessage()` method:

```
Handler cambiarHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {             
           texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto);
           texto.setText("ok");  

        }
    };
```

And in the onClick method do this to have new instance of the thread each time button is clicked.

```
public void onClick(View v){
new Thread (new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

                    try {

                                         Thread.sleep(3000);
                        cambiarHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }  

     }).start();
}
```