# Alert Dialog from Thread - Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, android-alertdialog

I have a thread that sends GPS coordinates to a database every six seconds and I have a check that verifies that the user is within a defined area. If the user is not within the location, I want an alert dialog that notifies them that they are out of range, and if they are within the area I want a dialog that tells them they are within range.

I have the checks working properly, but I have tried and I'm pretty sure that I can't add the dialog on the background thread. I have read a bit about using handlers. How can I implement one?

This is how I call `FindLocation.java` from my main activity (`MainActivity.java`):

```
new FindLocation(getBaseContext()).start(usr_id1); //sends a user id with it
```

Below is `FindLocation.java`

```
public class FindLocation extends Thread {

public boolean inJurisdiction;
public boolean AlertNotice = false;
private LocationManager locManager;
private LocationListener locListener;

Context ctx;
public String userId;

public FindLocation(Context ctx) {
     this.ctx = ctx;
}

 public void start(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        super.start();
      }

 @Override
public void run() {
     Looper.prepare();
    final String usr = userId;      
    
    //get a reference to the LocationManager
    locManager = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   
    //checked to receive updates from the position
    locListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            
            String lat = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()); 
            String lon = String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude());
            
            Double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
            Double longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                
            if (latitude >= 39.15296 && longitude >= -86.547546 && latitude <= 39.184901 && longitude <= -86.504288 || inArea != false) {
                Log.i("Test", "Yes");  
                
                inArea = true;
                
                JSONArray jArray;
                String result = null;
                InputStream is = null;
                StringBuilder sb = null;

                 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", usr));
                 
                //http post
                try{
                    
                     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/test/example.php");     
                     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                     is = entity.getContent();
                     }catch(Exception e){
                         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
                    }
                
                //convert response to string
                try{
                      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                       sb = new StringBuilder();
                       sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                
                       String line="0";
                       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                      sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        is.close();
                        result=sb.toString();
                        }
                
                        catch(Exception e){
                              Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                                

                        }
        
                try{
                      jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                      JSONObject json_data=null;
                      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                             json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                             String ct_name = json_data.getString("phoneID");
                             Log.i("User ID", ct_name);
                             if(ct_name == usr) {
                                 locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
                             }
                             else{
                                 locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
                                 Log.i("User ID", "NONE");
                             }
                         } 
                      }
        
                      catch(Exception e){
                            //Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                            
                            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/test/example.php");
    
                            try {
                                   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                                   nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat)); 
                                   nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", lon));
                                   nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", usr));
                                   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs1));
                                   httpclient.execute(httppost);
                                   Log.i("SendLocation", "Yes"); 
                             } 
                             catch (ClientProtocolException g) {
                                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                             } catch (IOException f) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } 
                } 
            } 
            
            else {
                Log.i("Test", "No");
                inArea = false;
            }
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ 
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
        }
    };
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 6000, 0, locListener);
    Looper.loop();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a little difficult to read the entire code, but I will show you how to display an `AlertDialog` from a background `Thread`:

Create a handler inside `onCreate()`, or `onResume()`... something that runs on the `UI-Thread`:

```
...onCreate(){
      //...
      mHandler=new Handler();
}
```

Then inside your `Thread()` just use:

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        //Be sure to pass your Activity class, not the Thread
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
        //... setup dialog and show
    }
});
```

Comment: I understand this, but I call this from my main activity and the entire class is essentially a thread. Since I don't have an onCreate for the the class, where would I instantiate the handler object?

Comment: you could just pass it as a parameter in the constructor of your Thread. the same way you pass the context.

Answer (score 9):

```
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {

                              //your alert dialog here..

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Where would I put this in the FindLocation class? Also, how do I call it? Would I use this twice, once if the user is within the defined location and once again if they are not? Thanks

Comment: see... whenever you want to display the alertdialog.. put this entire part there.. and create the alert dialog inside..

Comment: Ok I see. I have done that, but I get an error `The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type new LocationListener(){}` when I put it directly under `inArea = true;` (after the if(latitude >= ...)) Any idea why?

Comment: Same problem, but says "... is undefined for the type FindLocation." Got any other ideas?

Comment: [See this to use handler..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369537/update-ui-from-thread)

Comment: Well I'd like to continue using the thread. I had a lot of trouble getting the AsyncTask to work. Do I need to define something first?

Comment: I couldn.t get you.. did you see his answer?[Arhimed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369537/update-ui-from-thread)

Comment: See... i said youractivity.this.runonui thread.. and u were using a thread inplace of activity... put  MainActivity.this.runonUithread...

Comment: Did you try putting your activity name?

Answer (score 2):

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable{
 public void run(){

   //create your AlertDialog here.. 
  }

});
```

see more [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#handler)

Comment: This will not work from Android 8 to android 10