# How to use alert dialog in Handler and runOnUiThread in android

Tags: android, handler, android-runonuithread

I have added dialog in a thread but my dialog is crash.
Can anyone find an issue where I am wrong?

I have faced issue but I haven't found this solution.
I have already check this link : [Alert Dialog from Thread - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990242/alert-dialog-from-thread-android)

I have added this code in MyApplication class in my project.

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                        alert.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                        alert.setMessage("dsgdgd");
                        alert.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.app_name), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            }
                        });
                        alert.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
```

---

**My Error is :**
If I am using Handler then below error display.

```
04-28 15:31:11.999 5498-5558/com.sufalam.baseproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-1
    Process: com.sufalam.baseproject, PID: 5498
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
        at com.sufalam.baseproject.session.BaseActivity.onSessionLogout(BaseActivity.java:37)
        at com.sufalam.baseproject.session.MyApp$1.run(MyApp.java:24)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

---

**Using runOnUiThread :**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                alert.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                alert.setMessage("dsgdgd");
                alert.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.app_name), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    }
                });
                alert.show();

            }
        });
```

---

**My Error is :**

If I am using runOnUiThread then below error display.

```
04-28 15:37:31.830 6095-6095/com.sufalam.baseproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sufalam.baseproject, PID: 6095
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:694)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:316)
        at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1112)
        at com.sufalam.baseproject.session.BaseActivity$1.run(BaseActivity.java:46)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Answer (score 1):

don't use `AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());`

use `AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`

by putting your code in a new method

```
private void myMethod(AlertDialog.Builder alert){
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run () {

                    alert.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                    alert.setMessage("dsgdgd");
                    alert.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.app_name), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        }
                    });
                    alert.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();`}
```

then in your onCreate() call like this

`AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
myMethod(alert);`

Comment: Still, I am facing this issue some time. Error: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@f677885 is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: Still we are facing this error :  java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Go to your `theme.xml` and change like expalined there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity