# Timer and setContentView on Android

Tags: android, timer, set

I want to execute a piece of code
So that users can pay attention to my LOGO
Like other APP

I want to use timer Execution setContentView.
Compiler is not wrong.
But execution error.
unfortunately has stopped.

```
Timer timer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    abc();
}

        public void abc() {

             timer = new Timer();

            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                      goToLayout1();    
                }

                private void goToLayout1() {
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
                            timer.cancel();
                }
            }, 1000, 2000);
        }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you should have two activity.First activity is for showing splash screen.You can finish this after 3 seconds and start another activity that is activity with the layout actitiy_main2.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Runnable runnable=new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
    finish();
    //start main activity
      }
    };
  Handler handler=new Handler();
  handler.postDelayed(runnable,3000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you
I'm a beginner
Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

you are attempting to modify the UI thread from a non-UI thread (a simple java timer)
so please, take care of it and read this [Update UI from Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369537/update-ui-from-thread). Then please, post the exception!