# Android: Timer Task query

Tags: android, timertask

I have an app in which based on some click I start the timer using the TimerTask(). 
But I would also like to have support for multiple timers for multiple clicks. 
So if one timer is already working and another click is issued then it starts a separate timer thread and not just cancel the first one.

Could someone please help?

```
@Override
public void onListItemClicked(int index, Map<String, Object> data) {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
         int n = 0;
         @Override
         public void run() {        
             if (++n == 300) {
                 timer.cancel();
             }
             timer = null;
         }
    },1000,1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have things like this:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClicked(int index, Map<String, Object> data) {
    //you shouldn't have timer as class' property
    //if so your timer will cancel itself when you click again
    //local timer will be cancelled  when n is counted to 300 only
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        int n = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (++n == 300) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
            timer = null;
        }
    },1000,1000);
}
```

Comment: thanks, the only issue is that I don't know the max value and would be use dependent. Also, I want that for every click the respective timer starts. In your code, i think u start all  the together, that wouldn;t work

Comment: i got wrong what you meant. in the above code, the timertask doesn't share with each other, so you don't need to worry it will stop other timer.

Comment: see firstly u have assumed that the max number of timers would be 10 but it could be anything, infact the max number would change dynamically based on number of UI clicks. Also, each timer has to be started after the respective click and not wait till all  the clicks have been issued. I hope you get my point

Comment: that's for illustration only. sorry for haven't exlained it explicitly. See my edit

Comment: thanks this would work, but there is one more issue. Suppose the user, presses the 'Back' button to release this UI, I have to set all timers to null. if there are all local, then i won't be able to do that.

Comment: Then you maintain a array list of Timer, every click you create 1 timer and add it to the array list. When back is pressed you iterate through the list and cancel every one.