# How to respond to selection of a value of Spinner multiple times instead of one time?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I guess my title is not clear enough. Okay, let says in this way.

1- I have a spinner that acts as Filter. By default if user clicks on spinner, drop down list appears and displays my values.

2- When user selects item_1 then fragmentDialog appears and displays my lists. User is able to select an item and my fragment/activity will respond accordingly.

3- Now, if user click on spinner and selects item_1 again, drop down list closes and nothing happens. I want drop down list displays fragmentDialog again and let user to select another item.

It seems when user selects an item from drop-down list then by selecting same item onItemSelected() callback never invoke unless user click on another item.

Hope I could explain what is my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Post the code where you show the dialog, also please don't prefix your question's titles with keywords like android, git etc, the tags at the bottom are more than enough.

Comment: Thanks @Luksprog, About the code, It's not related to code. I was talking about default functionality of Spinner. So, I want to know how to modify it in a way that I need it. Thanks.

Comment: So you basically want multi selection on the spinner, no?

Comment: not multi selection when drop-down is open. 1- user clicks spinner, drop-down is open, user selects item 1, drop-down closes, dialog appears. 2- Now, if user clicks spinner, drop-down is open, user selects item 1 (again) then drop-down closes and dialog doesn't display. I want spinner display dialog again

Comment: Finally, I found my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19736914/513413