# Unable to redirect after Splash screen

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I havesetup a splash screen from where I want it to redirect to my main activity after 5 sec but my application always stays on the splash screen and never redirects.

I have following code in my `SplashActivity.Java`

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.SplashActivity);
        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // sleep(R.integer.SplashActivityTime);
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException iEx) {
                    iEx.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent mainActivity = new Intent(
                           "com.myApp.myApp.MainActivity");

                    startActivity(mainActivity);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

And in `Manifest` I Have:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.myApp.myApp.SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.myApp.myApp.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.myApp.myApp.MainActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the MainActivity.class in the intent instead?

Comment: `startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.myApp.myApp.MainActivity.class));`

Comment: check my answer in below link , it may help you .....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762484/using-a-thread-to-run-code-and-update-ui-android/18762649#18762649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                // sleep(R.integer.SplashActivityTime);
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException iEx) {
                iEx.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent mainActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        SecondActivity.class);

                startActivity(mainActivity);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

And in manifest

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.sample.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.sample.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Intent:

```
Intent mainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

In addition, which class is the owner of that `sleep`  method?

Answer (score 0):

Remove intent-filter for main activity's activity in manifest file

And best way to implement splash screen [click here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/)

and starting intent line change to

```
Intent mainActivity = new Intent(SplashActivity .this, MainActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
Thread logoTimer = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                sleep(3000);
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }//End of try block
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }//End of catch block
            finally
            {
                finish();
            }//End of finally block
        }//End of run method
    };//End of anonymous thread inner class
    logoTimer.start();
```

In `Manifest`

```
<activity
    android:name="com.myApp.myApp.SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
        android:name="com.myApp.myApp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Try this :

public class splashscreen extends Activity {

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash); // Your Splash Layout

        Handler handler = new Handler();

     // run a thread
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                // make sure we close the splash screen so the user won't come back when it presses back key

                finish();
                // start the home screen

                Intent intent = new Intent(splashscreen.this, TabDemo2Activity.class);
                splashscreen.this.startActivity(intent);

            }

        }, 5000); // time in milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds) until the run() method will be called

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Handler as below it's work for me.

Handler handler = new Handler();

```
// run a thread after 2 seconds to start the home screen

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
                if (!mIsBackButtonPressed) {
                    // start next activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, SEOshopMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
               } 
            }
        }, 2000); // time in milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds) until the run() method will be called
```