# Android exception when use new Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, exception

Hi guys i'm trying to make an app gets me battery status in real time through Toast message. So, if i plug battery charger it should me show "battery is charging", if i unplug charger it should me show "battery is discharging", etc...For this i'm using a new thread but on runtime my app crash and i get error in logcat

Here there are my code and logcat:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Context cxt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    cxt = this;


    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            IntentFilter IF = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
            Intent BatteryStatus = cxt.registerReceiver(null, IF);
            int status = BatteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
            boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;
            boolean disCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING;
            boolean usbCharge = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
            boolean acCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

            if (isCharging) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La batteria è in carica", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (disCharging) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La batteria è in scarica", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (usbCharge) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La batteria è in carica tramite USB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (acCharging) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La batteria è in carica tramite AC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
    myThread.start();

}
```

This is the error i get in my logcat:

```
01-04 11:10:10.696    7706-7723/com.example.matteo.battery E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4343
Process: com.example.matteo.battery, PID: 7706
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
        at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:336)
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:100)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:250)
        at com.example.matteo.battery.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:43)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I think i wrong something when try to start the new Thread.

Thanks everybody!

Comment: so how should i create that thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
if (isCharging) {
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "La batteria è in carica", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```

Apply to all Toast

not use thread. create a `BroadcastReceiver`

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
                boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;
                boolean disCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING;
                boolean usbCharge = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
                boolean acCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
                //your code

            }
        };
        IntentFilter IF = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, IF);
```

or

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
myThread.start();

            }
        };
        IntentFilter IF = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, IF);
```

Comment: i've done like you said and now when i launch my app it shows message only one time but not everytime i change battery status..what's wrong?

Comment: why? how could i take it alive?

Comment: check out my change in a reply

Answer (score 4):

you can't update your UI in non UI thread,

you get an error in `Toast` message,

if you want do some code in new thread and after that updated UI you can use `AsyncTask`, for more info about updating ui in new thread you can see  [Update UI from Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369537/update-ui-from-thread) or see  [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

Answer (score 1):

The Result you are trying to achieve can be done more easily using the Broadcast Receivers.
Have a look on the following [official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) of android developer site.

Answer (score 1):

Use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to run a specified action on the UI thread.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Context cxt;
Button bn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        cxt = this;


        Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                IntentFilter IF = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
                Intent BatteryStatus = cxt.registerReceiver(null, IF);
                int status = BatteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
                boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;
                boolean disCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING;
                boolean usbCharge = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
                boolean acCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

                if (isCharging) {
                    showMessage("La batteria è in carica");
                }
                if (disCharging) {
                    showMessage("La batteria è in scarica");
                }
                if (usbCharge) {
                    showMessage("La batteria è in carica tramite USB");
                }
                if (acCharging) {
                    showMessage("La batteria è in carica tramite AC");
                }
            }
        };

        Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
        myThread.start();

    }

    private void showMessage(final String msg) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i've done like you said and now when i launch my app it shows message only one time but not everytime i change battery status..i want Toast shows me battary status in real time