# Why the UI thread is getting blocked?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, ui-thread

In the below code I am trying to run a thread when a button is clicked. In the button listener I create a new thread and run it...but at run time, when the button is pressed, the button itself freezes and the app does not respond and I receive `ANR` dialog. Moreover, when the socket is connected successfully even the `TexView`

```
mtvStatus.setText("RFC-SOCKET CONNECTED");
```

displays nothing.

Please let me know why this is happening.

**button listener**:

```
this.mbtnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            BluetoothSocket rfcSocket = mSPPCtrl.rfcConnect();
            if (rfcSocket.isConnected()) {
                mtvStatus.setText("RFC-SOCKET CONNECTED");

                Thread rx = new Thread(new RxRun(rfcSocket));
                rx.run();

            } else {
                mtvStatus.setText("RFC-SOCKET NOT CONNECTED");
            }

        }
    });
```

**runnable class**

```
private class RxRun implements Runnable {

    private BluetoothSocket mRFCSocket = null;
    private OutputStream mRFCOS = null;
    private InputStream mRFCIS = null;

    public RxRun(BluetoothSocket rfcSocket) {
        this.mRFCSocket = rfcSocket;

        try {
            this.mRFCOS = rfcSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            this.mRFCIS = rfcSocket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.mRFCOS.write(DIRON.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (this.mRFCSocket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                int readBytes = this.mRFCIS.read(new byte[5120]);
                Log.d(TAG, CSubTag.bullet("RxRun", "readBytes:" + readBytes));
                //mtvRx.setText(""+readBytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you shoudnt call rx.run(), instead call rx.start();

Comment: You should use `rx.start();`  instead of `rx.run();`

Comment: Don't think you should be doing a .rfConnect() on your UI thread either...

Comment: Or why you shouldn't use `Thread` directly. Use an `ExecutorService` instead. The `.run()` method is inherited from `Runnable` and will not automagically run "in the background" for you. Also, how do you intend to collect the results?

Comment: @fge i am just making a test..and to answer your question "how do u intend to collect the result"? ..i want to display the result in the log.d inside the while loop..but it displays nothing and any log statement AFTER this line: int readBytes = this.mRFCIS.read(new byte[5120]); is never called...any suggestion why it is not getting called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...when the button is pressed, the button itself freezes and the app does not respond and I receive `ANR` dialog. Moreover, when the socket is connected successfully even the `TexView` displays nothing.

It's expected, because you haven't actually started the `rx` thread. Here is what is going on:

1. `mSPPCtrl` gets connected,
2. `mtvStatus`'s text is set to `"RFC-SOCKET CONNECTED"`, but you cannot visually see it because
3. `run()` method of the `RxRun` instance is called **manually** where the loop `while (this.mRFCSocket.isConnected())` may last as long as the socket is connected.

All the above said is invoked on `UI`-thread and that's the reason of `ANR`.

You should not call `run()` manually. Start the `rx` thread with

```
rx.start();
```

Also I highly recommend to move all the `rfcSocket` logic inside of the thread and notify the `UI`-thread on success/failure of connection.

### EDIT

Here is one the option mentioned in my comment.

Start the `rx` thread on a button click

```
this.mbtnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Thread(new RxRun(rfcSocket)).start();
    }
});
```

Move your logic inside of the `run()` method:

```
public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket rfcSocket = mSPPCtrl.rfcConnect();
        if (rfcSocket.isConnected()) {
            mtvStatus.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mtvStatus.setText("RFC-SOCKET CONNECTED");
                }
            });
        } else {
            mtvStatus.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mtvStatus.setText("RFC-SOCKET NOT CONNECTED");
                }
            });
            return;
        }
    // the rest of your logic
    }
```

Some links that might help:

1. Android documentation on [Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads)
2. SO question [Android basics: running code in the UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850143/android-basics-running-code-in-the-ui-thread)
3. another SO post on [Update UI from Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369537/update-ui-from-thread)

Comment: thanks for ur answer..would u please tell me more about notify() method why it should be used..is it like "return"

Comment: @LetsamrIt No, I didn't mean the `Object`'s `notify()` method, I used it as a verb. There are several options to "inform" a UI-thread from a background thread. Like by means of `Handler`, `runOnUiThread()` method if you passed a context to the background thread, `Observer` pattern implementation or a direct call of an `YourActivity` method (within which views must be touched on UI-thread only). Just use one of the techniques. If you really need help at this I'll edit the answer tomorrow (I'm almost asleep... :))

Answer (score 1):

The error here is really simple - do not use `run()` on the Thread instance, as this will actually *run it's Runnable on the current Thread*! Use `start()` and it will work fine :-)