# Android: setLayoutParams after load completed

Tags: android, multithreading

I want set 55000 height to `ListView`

This process long a time ( about 5-6 seconds )

I use below code but not working in Thread

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
            params.height = 55000;
            lstContent.setLayoutParams(params);
            lstContent.requestLayout();
            lstContent.post(new Runnable() {

                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                                lstContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      }
                });

            }
  }).start();
```

If i use `setLayoutParams` in `Runnable` , application not work for 5-6 seconds until load complete

Comment: i think the ui should be modified only on the `main/ui` thread. [link](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

Comment: Can you help me more ?

Comment: You could try the following links: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369537/update-ui-from-thread) and [link2](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-non-ui-to-ui-thread-communications-part-1-of-5/)

Comment: Thank your, but this article not work for me

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no reason to make a list view with the height of 55000. List view should be MATCH_PARENT at most. The whole purpose of list view is reusing views, that way the list view appear to be long, while it takes only the height of the screen.