# How would i pass a timer from one fragment to another?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Suppose i have a timer which uses a `TextView` in Fragment A. And i want to use this timer in Fragment B. How would i do it? This is the code which is being used in Fragment A to set the timer...

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

        // Displaying total duration time
        songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
        // Displaying current time
        songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

        // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
```

Now i want to use the timer that's associated with the `songCurrentDurationLabel` TextView, in Fragment B as well.

How would i go about solving this?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't update your UI from outside of your main thread.

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: check the explanation to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369537/update-ui-from-thread *but* do not use AsyncTask, you will run into problems later on (like memory leaks when you rotate the device). Read more about it here: http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/

Answer (score 0):

Use timer in the host Activity and set/post results as callbacks.
Android UI toolkit is not thread-safe - don’t access the UI from outside the UI thread.

Check some [gotchas](http://mgolokhov.github.io/processes_and_threads/).