# Can AsyncTask be executed from background thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

While reading the documentation, I found that **The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread**. But I am surprised that AsyncTask can also be executed from the worker thread.

So the question is:

1. If AsyncTask can also execute from the background thread, Why in the documentation they are saying just opposite to it.
2. How could it possible to have context on onPostExecute.?

   ```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
               @Override
               protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                   return null;
               }

               @Override
               protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                   super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "in AsyncTask...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }.execute();
       }
   }).start();
   ```

Comment: you are slightly misunderstood it here! AsyncTask must be triggered from main thread (you can say UI thread too). and moreover it is running in worker thread (you can say separate thread too)

Comment: `AsyncTask must be triggered from main thread`. Well OP just showed code to execute such a task from a worker thread. So please react to the point. @Radhey.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4918811/1848157 and https://www.quora.com/in/How-many-threads-are-there-in-AsyncTask-on-Android , gives you some useful information.

Comment: @Radhey I am not talking about how many threads are there in asynckTask, But my question is about the execution of asyncTask from the worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

The AsyncTask Android class lets us sort of bind background tasks to the UI thread. So using this class, you can perform background operations and then publish the results to the UI thread that updates the UI components.

you can understand AsyncTask execution briefly : http://codetheory.in/android-asynctask/

Comment: ????? You did not react on `But I am surprised that AsyncTask can also be executed from the worker thread.`. Nor answered any question.

Answer (score 0):

There is two Threads  Main Thread and Worker Thread. Asyntasck works on worker thread.Mostly Asynctask used for background Task.It works on worker thread and publish the result on Main thread.

If Main thread block for 5 sec or more than that Application not responding (ANR) dialogs comes so to avoid this scenario for background task Asynctask used

Comment: ????? You did not react on `But I am surprised that AsyncTask can also be executed from the worker thread.`. Nor answered any question.