# Create Handler in a class without get error "Looper not prepared"?

Tags: android, handler, looper

In my game, there is an game object class that need to use Handler to post a delay Runnable. However, everything I try to create an Handler in the object class, I receive error message:

> Can't create handler inside thread
>   that has not called Looper.prepare()

I've Googled some solution, but all of them use another solution, not Handler. Is there any solution to use Handler in a normal class? Or any solution to run a Runnable after a determined delay?

I can't use sleep, because it paused all my game!

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193913/handlers-messagequeue-looper-do-they-all-run-on-the-ui-thread as well. The answer discusses Handlers, the looper etc. a bit in-depth. It sure gave me some insights, maybe it can help you too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably creating the `Handler` from a non-UI thread. Either (1) you attach your handler explicitly to the UI thread by passing the UI thread's looper to `Handler`s constructor, which means that messages posted to the `Handler` are also executed on the UI thread, or (2) you create a new `Looper` for the non-UI-thread: see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html).

*edit* regarding (1): you would have to somehow pass the UI thread's looper to the "game object", for example when it is created. You can get a reference to UI's looper by calling `getMainLooper()` on a context (e.g. from an activity).

An alternative would be to create the handler in the activity and just pass the handler to your game object.

Comment: @user634618 Thank you for your advice! Creating a Handler in Activity and pass it to the object is the best and simplest solution!