# Android Looper and call stack

Tags: android, multithreading

I was wondering how the Looper class actually processes Runnables (via the Handler class) in the Thread that the Looper is attached to? If a looper is looping through its messageQueue then surely it would be a blocking operation for that thread? I imagine it itself must be performing some threading trickery but then how does it add the posted Runnables run() method onto the host threads stack?

Many questions! Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

Looking through the Looper [class file](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/os/Looper.java&q=package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org%20file%3aandroid/os/Looper.java&l=1) class i see the below, which confuses me even more as all comments refer to the looper running in the main thread but also that its a blocking operation while waiting for new messages on the MessageQueue. How is this not blocking the UI / main thread???

```
    /**
     *  Run the message queue in this thread. Be sure to call
     * {@link #quit()} to end the loop.
     */
    public static final void loop() {
        Looper me = myLooper();
        MessageQueue queue = me.mQueue;

        // Make sure the identity of this thread is that of the local process,
        // and keep track of what that identity token actually is.
        Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
        final long ident = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();

        while (true) {
            Message msg = queue.next(); // might block
            //if (!me.mRun) {
            //    break;
            //}
            if (msg != null) {
                if (msg.target == null) {
                    // No target is a magic identifier for the quit message.
                    return;
                }
                if (me.mLogging!= null) me.mLogging.println(
                        ">>>>> Dispatching to " + msg.target + " "
                        + msg.callback + ": " + msg.what
                        );
                msg.target.dispatchMessage(msg);
                if (me.mLogging!= null) me.mLogging.println(
                        "<<<<< Finished to    " + msg.target + " "
                        + msg.callback);

                // Make sure that during the course of dispatching the
                // identity of the thread wasn't corrupted.
                final long newIdent = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
                if (ident != newIdent) {
                    Log.wtf("Looper", "Thread identity changed from 0x"
                            + Long.toHexString(ident) + " to 0x"
                            + Long.toHexString(newIdent) + " while dispatching to "
                            + msg.target.getClass().getName() + " "
                            + msg.callback + " what=" + msg.what);
                }

                msg.recycle();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Returns the application's main looper, which lives in the main thread of the application.
     */
    public synchronized static final Looper getMainLooper() {
        return mMainLooper;
    }

   /**
     * Return the Looper object associated with the current thread.  Returns
     * null if the calling thread is not associated with a Looper.
     */
    public static final Looper myLooper() {
        return (Looper)sThreadLocal.get();
    }

    // sThreadLocal.get() will return null unless you've called prepare().
    private static final ThreadLocal sThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal();

    /** Initialize the current thread as a looper.
      * This gives you a chance to create handlers that then reference
      * this looper, before actually starting the loop. Be sure to call
      * {@link #loop()} after calling this method, and end it by calling
      * {@link #quit()}.
      */
    public static final void prepare() {
        if (sThreadLocal.get() != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Only one Looper may be created per thread");
        }
        sThreadLocal.set(new Looper());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looking around Stack I have found another question which answers mine. My main confusion was coming from a not realising the below from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193913/handlers-messagequeue-looper-do-they-all-run-on-the-ui-thread). I was incorrectly thinking of everything apart from the stuff posted to Handlers (and added to the Loopers MessageQueue) was being executed in a linear call stack, but thinking about it this is more likely how any program with a UI is implemented, and makes a lot more sense that every thing on the UI thread originated from the Looper and all paths of excecution on this thread will lead back to it! Thanks to Berdon for attempting to answer my question, im sure i didnt explain my issue well enough :)

> Regarding the android UI thread: At some point (probably before any
>   activities and the like are created) the framework has set up a Looper
>   (containing a MessageQueue) and started it. From this point on,
>   **everything that happens on the UI thread is through that loop**. This
>   includes activity lifecycle management and so on. All callbacks you
>   override (onCreate(), onDestroy()...) are at least indirecty
>   dispatched from that loop. You can see that for example in the stack
>   trace of an exception. (You can try it, just write int a = 1 / 0;
>   somewhere in onCreate()...)

Answer (score 2):

You're absolutely right. The originating thread that constructs Looper.start() is called on becomes the thread that all posted Runnables and Messages are handled on. This *indeed* means that this thread is blocked.

Comment: While i understand the thread excecutes the run() method and therefore cant be excecuting anything else at the time, I was more interested in how the looper can be checking for any items in the message queue on that thread without blocking (does that make sense?)

Comment: The Looper handles periodically checking for queued messages on the Thread while waiting (non-blocking) in-between checks.

Comment: how does one implement a non blocking wait without utilising another tread?

Comment: A loop with a job queue. ie. Loop, perform job one (checking messages), loop, perform job two (something else), loop, job one, etc.

Comment: but if your main thread is just looping through and executing runnables surely that will allow nothing else to excecute on that thread i.e. not be able to move through the call stack?

Comment: That's generally why you do use a separate thread for taxing jobs and leave UI specific operations for the UI thread.

Comment: Hi, I understand about not running long running tasks on the UI thread, my issue is with how a non-blocking loop is running on the UI thread (when in the code above it says it will run on the UI thread and perform a block!)

Comment: @Berdon let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2280/discussion-between-dori-and-berdon)