# How to post callbacks in Android to any arbitrary thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, looper

I am using the Unity game engine which also supports exporting to Android.

The engine uses multiple threads, including the UI thread and a separate scripting thread where all the user custom code is executing.

My scenario requires that i call some operation in a background thread, and i would like to marshal the result back to the main scripting thread.

I know the basics of the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) and [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) classes. Out of these, Looper seems like a good candidate since it allows setting up a queue and post back messages to a given thread (AsyncTask is "hardwired" to run the callback on the UI thread, which is not what i want here).

What is the proper way of achieving this?

Comment: Handler will help you in to call operation in a background thread.

Comment: What about custom BroadcastReceiver ?

Comment: @DonChakkappan I believe Handler will do it, as proposed in the comment above. I haven't worked with one but i will check the documentation for that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 3 main ways to communicate with the UI thread :

1. [Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)
2. [View.post(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29)
3. [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

In your case, I advice you to create an `Handler`, as the 2 first solutions imply that you have a reference on your `Activity` or a `View`

**Edit**

If you want to use any thread in your app, just make sure a `Looper` has been set, and use an associated `Handler`

```
class YourLooperThread extends Thread
{
    // make it accessible from the outside
    private Handler handler;

    @Override public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();

        // Customize your handler, it has to be used in any thread which want to push a message in this thread's looper message Queue
        handler = new Handler();

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

**Be careful** : all the other tasks you want to do in that thread must be done through the message queue, i.e posting a runnable in the handler. More information here : [Handlers, MessageQueue, Looper, do they all run on the UI thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193913/handlers-messagequeue-looper-do-they-all-run-on-the-ui-thread)

Comment: Thanks. My question specifically mentioned though that i don't want to execute on the UI thread, but on any arbitrary thread in the process.

Comment: Thanks. Does that have to be placed in a custom Thread class? the situation i have is a thread that was already created by the framework. Can i add a Handler and a Looper to that and expose the Handler to other threads to post to ? Also, what do you mean by all tasks should be done through the message queue ?

Comment: This question will help you understand : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984263/android-looper-and-call-stack A Looper, when it is looping, will block your thread, so this one will not be able to perfom any other operation. If this thread comes from a framework, it could be a problem.