# What is the purpose of Looper and how to use it?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-looper

I am new to Android. I want to know what the `Looper` class does and also how to use it. I have read the Android [Looper class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) but I am unable to completely understand it.
I have seen it in a lot of places but unable to understand its purpose. Can anyone help me by defining the purpose of `Looper` and also by giving a simple example if possible?

Comment: I just found an extraordinarily thorough and clear explanation of Looper and its use on Safari Books Online. Unfortunately, I suspect access if free for only a limited time. https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/efficient-android-threading/9781449364120/ch04.html

Comment: Android articles and reference pages require you to have and understanding of a previous article , before you can grasp the current one. I suggest you read the Activity and Service articles in the Api guides , and then read Handler and Looper. It also helps if you have an understanding of what a thread is(not an android thread, but a thread in general...e.g. POSIX).

Comment: I found this article useful: http://codetheory.in/android-handlers-runnables-loopers-messagequeue-handlerthread/

Comment: Creates an infinite loop for the thread to execute through so thread can check a task queue on each iteration, and execute the task. The task is called a message. This is a common design pattern called an event loop, just abstracted. If more than one thread share an event loop, you have a thread pool. Main thread must have the loop by default because is a non terminating thread that waits for ui event tasks. Other non terminating types of programs like video games have the event loop. Plain old threads do not have the loop, but can be added with looper api.

Comment: @JoeLapp thanks for the link, I am trying to understand the code, and I believe the line: `while(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){` inside `class TextHandlerTask` should be inverted for it to loop as in: `while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){`, this means that it will reattempt reading UNTIL the thread gets interrupted, Am I getting this right?

Comment: @JoeLapp It is year 2023 now and your [O'reilly Chapter 4. Thread Communication](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/efficient-android-threading/9781449364120/ch04.html) link still works! Amazing.

Answer (score 438, accepted):

**What is Looper?**

Looper is a class which is used to execute the Messages(Runnables) in a queue. Normal threads have no such queue, e.g. simple thread does not have any queue. It executes once and after method execution finishes, the thread will not run another Message(Runnable).

**Where we can use Looper class?**

If someone wants to execute multiple messages(Runnables) then he should use the Looper class which is responsible for creating a queue in the thread.
For example, while writing an application that downloads files from the internet, we can use Looper class to put files to be downloaded in the queue.

**How it works?**

There is `prepare()` method to prepare the Looper. Then you can use `loop()` method to create a message loop in the current thread and now your Looper is ready to execute the requests in the queue until you quit the loop.

Here is the code by which you can prepare the Looper.

```
class LooperThread extends Thread {
      public Handler mHandler;

      @Override
      public void run() {
          Looper.prepare();

          mHandler = new Handler() {
              @Override
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // process incoming messages here
              }
          };

          Looper.loop();
      }
  }
```

Comment: So looper could be used to update the main thread with lets say... a download percentage (10%, 20%, 30% ... etc). Essentially feedback which you could feed into a progressbar?

Comment: An AsyncTask is better for that purpose and less complex as it encapsulates all the thread managing.

Comment: Should have @Override annotations before the run() and handleMessage() methods

Comment: As we are overriding these method it should @override above these run and handleMessage methods

Comment: The documentation indicates that you must call looper.quit. In your code above, Looper.loop will block indefinitely.

Comment: I'm confused, how to you get Looper.loop() to not block? Why would you call Looper.Quit() if you want the message loop for the thread to run?

Comment: How to quit a loop. I mean where to include Looper.quit() in the above code example?

Comment: As far as I know you can call Looper.myLooper().quit(); to quite the current lopper loop. You can call this method when you got particular message in handleMessage method.

Comment: Calling quit  is optional depending on  use case.

Comment: Andi; you would quit after processing messages so could then dedicate that thread to post monitoring duty for example. Eg thread sits there waiting for async seeds to arrive.  When has them quit monitoring and do some work on that same thread.

Comment: I think it would be better to use [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) which is a convenient class for a thread with a looper.

Comment: How to quit looper is simple just  call the quit method of the called Thread in  onDestroy(). mWorkerThread.quit()  will check it has looper or not and will be terminated. Javadoc:  "Causes the handler thread's looper to terminate without processing any more messages in the message queue"

Comment: @Andromeda Does `Looper.quit()`scope be available in `onDestroy()`  method?

Comment: @– rkm_Hodor  while onDestroy, just call the yourThread.quit()  method it will handle the looper inside of this. But this is valid for HandlerThreads which handle looper staff instead of you.  If you create your own thread and own Looper implementation you should handle with your looper by simply adding quit() method to your thread.   public boolean quit() {
        Looper looper = getLooper();
        if (looper != null) {
            looper.quit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: This doesn't explain why one would use this class, only how.

Comment: Amazing...Does anyone understand how to send message to LooperThread? Its totally unuseful example. Everyone just copied stupid example from documentation.

Answer (score 409):

You can better understand what Looper is in the context of the GUI framework. Looper is made to do 2 things.

1. Looper transforms a normal thread into something run continuously until Android app is running.
2. Looper provides a queue where jobs to be done are enqueued.

As you may know, when an application is launched, the system creates a thread of execution for the application, called “main”, and Android applications normally run entirely on a single thread by default the “main thread”. But **main thread is not a secret, special thread**. It's just a normal thread similar to one you can create with `new Thread()`, which means it terminates when its `run()` method returns! Think of below example.

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
    }
}
```

Now, let's apply this simple principle to Android apps. What would happen if an Android app runs on a normal thread? A thread called "main" or "UI" or whatever starts your application and draws all UI. So the first screen is displayed to users. What now? The main thread terminates? No, it shouldn’t. It should wait until users do something, right? But how can we achieve this behavior? Well, we can try with `Object.wait()` or `Thread.sleep()`. For example, main thread finishes its initial job to display first screen, and sleeps. It awakes, which means interrupted, when a new job to do is fetched. So far so good, but at this moment we need a queue-like data structure to hold multiple jobs. Think about a case when a user touches screen serially, and a task takes longer time to finish. So, we need to have a data structure to hold jobs to be done in first-in-first-out manner. Also, you may imagine, implementing ever-running-and-process-job-when-arrived thread using interrupt is not easy, and leads to complex and often unmaintainable code. We'd rather create a new mechanism for such purpose, and ***that is what Looper is all about***. The [official document of Looper class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) says, "Threads by default do not have a message loop associated with them", and Looper is a class "used to run a message loop for a thread". Now you can understand what it means.

To make things more clear, let's check the code where the main thread is transformed. It all happens in [ActivityThread class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java). In its main() method, you can find below code, which turns a normal thread into something that we need.

```
public final class ActivityThread {
    ...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        Looper.prepareMainLooper();
        Looper.loop();
        ...
    }
}
```

and `Looper.loop()` method loop infinitely and dequeue a message and process one at a time:

```
public static void loop() {
    ...
    for (;;) {
        Message msg = queue.next(); // might block
        if (msg == null) {
            // No message indicates that the message queue is quitting.
            return;
        }
        ...
        msg.target.dispatchMessage(msg);
        ...
    }
}
```

So, basically, Looper is a class that is made to address a problem that occurs in the GUI framework. But this kind of need can also happen in other situations as well. Actually, it is a pretty famous pattern for multi-thread applications, and you can learn more about it in "*Concurrent Programming in Java*" by Doug Lea(Especially, chapter 4.1.4 "Worker Threads" would be helpful). Also, you can imagine this kind of mechanism is not unique in Android framework, but all GUI framework may need somewhat similar. You can find almost same mechanism in Java Swing framework too.

Comment: Quick question. You stated that in the main thread after it draws out all of the UI elements it is put to sleep. But let's say the user interacts with a button on the screen, isn't that button click even put into a main queue, then some object will dispatch it to the correct activity, then the main thread for that activity is awake and it will execute the code for in the callback for that button click?

Answer (score 82):

Looper allows tasks to be executed sequentially on a single thread. And handler defines those tasks that we need to be executed. It is a typical scenario that I am trying to illustrate in this example:

```
class SampleLooper extends Thread {
@Override
public void run() {
  try {
    // preparing a looper on current thread     
    // the current thread is being detected implicitly
    Looper.prepare();

    // now, the handler will automatically bind to the
    // Looper that is attached to the current thread
    // You don't need to specify the Looper explicitly
    handler = new Handler();

    // After the following line the thread will start
    // running the message loop and will not normally
    // exit the loop unless a problem happens or you
    // quit() the looper (see below)
    Looper.loop();
  } catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e(TAG, "halted due to an error", t);
  } 
}
}
```

Now we can use the handler in some other threads(say ui thread) to post the task on Looper to execute.

```
handler.post(new Runnable()
{
public void run() {
//This will be executed on thread using Looper.
    }
});
```

On UI thread we have an implicit Looper that allow us to handle the messages on ui thread.

Comment: it will not lock any UI Process, is it true?

Comment: Thanks for including sample on how to post "jobs" to the queue

Comment: This doesn't explain why one would use this class, only how.

Comment: Is SampleLooper inner class?

Answer (score 41):

Android `Looper` is a wrapper to attach `MessageQueue` to `Thread` and it manages Queue processing. It looks very cryptic in Android documentation and many times we may face `Looper` related UI access issues. If we don't understand the basics it becomes very tough to handle.

Here is an [article](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.kr/2013/09/android-looper-and-toast-from.html) which explains `Looper` life cycle, how to use it and usage of `Looper` in `Handler`

[image]

**Looper = Thread + MessageQueue**

Comment: This doesn't explain why one would use this class, only how.

Comment: @AndrewKoster IMHO it addresses the "why" by *"to attach MessageQueue to Thread*".

Comment: @WebViewer The answer from 김준호 has a much more complete explanation. Attaching a MessageQueue to a Thread isn't a useful end goal, so it doesn't really get us much closer to answering "why". The answer from 김준호 gets into the use cases, and the use cases are the actual reason to use the class.

Comment: @AndrewKoster Thanks for explaining this. Do you know whether there is an upper limit to number of Looper instances in an Android app?

Answer (score 18):

**Simplest Definition of Looper & Handler:**

*Looper* is a class that turns a thread into a **Pipeline Thread** and *Handler* gives you a mechanism to push tasks into this pipe from any other threads.

**Details in general wording:**

So a **PipeLine Thread** is a thread which can accept more tasks from other threads through a Handler.

The **Looper** is named so because it implements the loop – takes the next task, executes it, then takes the next one and so on. The Handler is called a handler because it is used to handle or accept that next task each time from any other thread and pass to Looper (Thread or PipeLine Thread).

**Example:**

A Looper and Handler or PipeLine Thread's very perfect example is to download more than one images or upload them to a server (Http) one by one in a single thread instead of starting a new Thread for each network call in the background.

Read more here about Looper and Handler and the definition of Pipeline Thread:

[Android Guts: Intro to Loopers and Handlers](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/)

Answer (score 14):

### Understanding Looper Threads

A java Thread a unit of execution which was designed to perform a task in its run() method  & terminate after that:
[image]

But in Android there are many use cases where we need to keep a Thread alive and wait for user inputs/events for eg. UI thread aka `Main Thread`.

Main thread  in Android is a Java thread which is first started by JVM at the launch of an app and keeps on running till the user choose to close it or encounters unhandled exception.

> When an application is launched, the system creates a thread of
>   execution for the application, called "main." This thread is very
>   important because it is in charge of dispatching events to the
>   appropriate user interface widgets, including drawing events.

[image]

**Now point to note here is although main thread is Java thread yet it keeps on listening to user events and draw 60 fps frames on screen and still it wont die after each cycle. how is it so?**

> **The answer is Looper Class**: Looper is a class which is used to keep a thread alive and manage a message queue to execute tasks on
>   that thread.

Threads by default do not have a message loop associated with them but you can assign one by calling  Looper.prepare() in the run method and then call the Looper.loop().

> Purpose of Looper is to keep a Thread alive and wait for next cycle of
>   input `Message` object to perform computation which otherwise will get
>   destroyed after first cycle of execution.

If you want to dig deeper how Looper manage `Message` object queue then you can have a look at source code of `Looperclass`:

> https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/Looper.java

Below is an example of how you can create a `Looper Thread` and communicate with `Activity` class using `LocalBroadcast`

```
class LooperThread : Thread() {

    // sendMessage success result on UI
    private fun sendServerResult(result: String) {
        val resultIntent = Intent(ServerService.ACTION)
        resultIntent.putExtra(ServerService.RESULT_CODE, Activity.RESULT_OK)
        resultIntent.putExtra(ServerService.RESULT_VALUE, result)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(AppController.getAppController()).sendBroadcast(resultIntent)
    }

    override fun run() {
        val looperIsNotPreparedInCurrentThread = Looper.myLooper() == null

        // Prepare Looper if not already prepared
        if (looperIsNotPreparedInCurrentThread) {
            Looper.prepare()
        }

        // Create a handler to handle messaged from Activity
        handler = Handler(Handler.Callback { message ->
            // Messages sent to Looper thread will be visible here
            Log.e(TAG, "Received Message" + message.data.toString())

            //message from Activity
            val result = message.data.getString(MainActivity.BUNDLE_KEY)

            // Send Result Back to activity
            sendServerResult(result)
            true
        })

        // Keep on looping till new messages arrive
        if (looperIsNotPreparedInCurrentThread) {
            Looper.loop()
        }
    }

    //Create and send a new  message to looper
    fun sendMessage(messageToSend: String) {
        //Create and post a new message to handler
        handler!!.sendMessage(createMessage(messageToSend))
    }


    // Bundle Data in message object
    private fun createMessage(messageToSend: String): Message {
        val message = Message()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString(MainActivity.BUNDLE_KEY, messageToSend)
        message.data = bundle
        return message
    }

    companion object {
        var handler: Handler? = null // in Android Handler should be static or leaks might occur
        private val TAG = javaClass.simpleName

    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var looperThread: LooperThread? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // start looper thread
        startLooperThread()

        // Send messages to Looper Thread
        sendMessage.setOnClickListener {

            // send random messages to looper thread
            val messageToSend = "" + Math.random()

            // post message
            looperThread!!.sendMessage(messageToSend)

        }   
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        //Register to Server Service callback
        val filterServer = IntentFilter(ServerService.ACTION)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(serverReceiver, filterServer)

    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()

        //Stop Server service callbacks
     LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(serverReceiver)
    }


    // Define the callback for what to do when data is received
    private val serverReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val resultCode = intent.getIntExtra(ServerService.RESULT_CODE, Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val resultValue = intent.getStringExtra(ServerService.RESULT_VALUE)
                Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "Server result : $resultValue")

                serverOutput.text =
                        (serverOutput.text.toString()
                                + "\n"
                                + "Received : " + resultValue)

                serverScrollView.post( { serverScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN) })
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startLooperThread() {

        // create and start a new LooperThread
        looperThread = LooperThread()
        looperThread!!.name = "Main Looper Thread"
        looperThread!!.start()

    }

    companion object {
        val BUNDLE_KEY = "handlerMsgBundle"
        private val TAG = javaClass.simpleName
    }
}
```

**Can we use Async task or Intent Services instead?**

- Async tasks are designed to perform a short operation in background and give progres & results on UI thread. Async tasks have limits like you cant create more than **128 Async tasks** and `ThreadPoolExecutor` will allow only **upto 5 Async tasks**.
- `IntentServices` are also designed to do background task for a little longer duration and you can use `LocalBroadcast` to communicate with `Activity`. But services get destroyed after task execution. If you want to keep it running for a long time than you need to do hecks like  `while(true){...}`.

**Other meaningful use cases for Looper Thread:**

- Used for 2 way socket communication where server keep on listening to Client socket and write back acknowledgment
- Bitmap processing in background. Pass the image url to Looper thread and it will apply filter effects and store it in tempe rory location and then  broadcast temp path of image.

Answer (score 7):

A [Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) has a `synchronized` `MessageQueue` that's used to process Messages placed on the queue.

It implements a `Thread` Specific Storage Pattern.

Only one `Looper` per `Thread`. Key methods include `prepare()`,`loop()` and `quit()`.

`prepare()` initializes the current `Thread` as a `Looper`. `prepare()` is `static` method that uses the `ThreadLocal` class as shown below.

```
   public static void prepare(){
       ...
       sThreadLocal.set
       (new Looper());
   }
```

1. `prepare()` must be called explicitly before running the event loop.
2. `loop()` runs the event loop which waits for Messages to arrive on a specific Thread's messagequeue. Once the next Message is received,the `loop()` method dispatches the Message to its target handler
3. `quit()` shuts down the event loop. It doesn't terminate the loop,but instead it enqueues a special message

`Looper` can be programmed in a `Thread` via several steps

1. Extend `Thread`
2. Call `Looper.prepare()` to initialize Thread as a `Looper`
3. Create one or more `Handler`(s) to process the incoming messages
4. Call `Looper.loop()` to process messages until the loop is told to `quit()`.

Answer (score 7):

Life span of java [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) is over after completion of `run()` method. Same thread can't be started again.

[Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) transforms normal `Thread` into a message loop. Key methods of `Looper` are :

```
void prepare ()
```

> Initialize the current thread as a looper. This gives you a chance to create handlers that then reference this looper, before actually starting the loop. Be sure to call loop() after calling this method, and end it by calling quit().

```
void loop ()
```

> Run the message queue in this thread. Be sure to call quit() to end the loop.

```
void quit()
```

> Quits the looper.
>
> Causes the loop() method to terminate without processing any more messages in the message queue.

This [mindorks article](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a) by Janishar explains the core concepts in nice way.

[image]

`Looper` is associated with a Thread. If you need `Looper` on UI thread, `Looper.getMainLooper()` will return associated thread.

You need `Looper` to be associated with a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

`Looper`, `Handler`, and `HandlerThread` are the Android’s way of solving the problems of asynchronous programming.

Once you have `Handler`, you can call below APIs.

```
post (Runnable r)
```

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue. The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.

```
boolean sendMessage (Message msg)
```

> Pushes a message onto the end of the message queue after all pending messages before the current time. It will be received in handleMessage(Message), in the thread attached to this handler.

[HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) is handy class for starting a new thread that has a looper. The looper can then be used to create handler classes

In some scenarios, you can't run `Runnable` tasks on UI Thread. 
e.g. Network operations : Send message on a socket, open an URL and get content by reading `InputStream`

In these cases, `HandlerThread` is useful. You can get `Looper` object from `HandlerThread` and create a `Handler` on `HandlerThread` instead of main thread.

The [HandlerThread](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/os/HandlerThread.java/?v=source) code will be like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    mTid = Process.myTid();
    Looper.prepare();
    synchronized (this) {
        mLooper = Looper.myLooper();
        notifyAll();
    }
    Process.setThreadPriority(mPriority);
    onLooperPrepared();
    Looper.loop();
    mTid = -1;
}
```

Refer to below post for example code:

[Android: Toast in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread/45922317#45922317)

Answer (score 5):

This answer has nothing to do with the question, but the use of looper and the way people created the handler and looper in ALL the answers here are plain bad practice (some explanations are correct though), I have to post this:

```
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread(threadName);
thread.start();
Looper looper = thread.getLooper();
Handler myHandler = new Handler(looper);
```

and for a [full implementation](https://github.com/nu-art/cyborg-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nu/art/cyborg/core/modules/ThreadsModule.java)

Answer (score 4):

> What is Looper?

FROM DOCS

[**`Looper`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper)

`Looper` Class used to run a message loop for a `thread`. Threads by default do not have a message loop associated with them; to create one, call `prepare()` in the thread that is to run the loop, and then `loop()` to have it process messages until the loop is stopped.

- A `Looper` is a message handling loop:
- An important character of Looper is that it's associated with the thread within which the Looper is created
- The Looper class maintains a [`MessageQueue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue), which contains a list messages. An important character of Looper is that it's associated with the thread within which the Looper is created.
- The `Looper` is named so because it implements the loop – takes the next task, executes it, then takes the next one and so on. The `Handler` is called a handler because someone could not invent a better name
- Android `Looper` is a Java class within the Android user interface that together with the Handler class to process UI events such as button clicks, screen redraws and orientation switches.

> How it works?

[image]

> Creating Looper

A thread gets a `Looper` and [`MessageQueue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue) by calling `Looper.prepare()` after its running. `Looper.prepare()` identifies the calling thread, creates a Looper and `MessageQueue` object and associate the thread

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
class MyLooperThread extends Thread {

      public Handler mHandler; 

      public void run() { 

          // preparing a looper on current thread  
          Looper.prepare();

          mHandler = new Handler() { 
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
                 // process incoming messages here
                 // this will run in non-ui/background thread
              } 
          }; 

          Looper.loop();
      } 
  }
```

For more information check below post

- [What is the relationship between Looper, Handler and MessageQueue in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877944/what-is-the-relationship-between-looper-handler-and-messagequeue-in-android)
- [Android Guts: Intro to Loopers and Handlers](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/)
- [Understanding Android Core: Looper, Handler, and HandlerThread](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a)
- [Handler in Android](https://medium.com/@ankit.sinhal/handler-in-android-d138c1f4980e)
- [What Is Android Looper?](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/android-looper-37719.html)
- [Android: Looper, Handler, HandlerThread. Part I.](https://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/)
- [MessageQueue and Looper in Android](https://medium.com/@ankit.sinhal/messagequeue-and-looper-in-android-3a18c7fc9181)

Answer (score 3):

Handling multiple down or upload items in a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is a better example.

`Handler` and `AsnycTask` are often used to propagate *Events/Messages* between the *UI (thread) and a worker thread* or to delay actions. So they are more related  to UI.

A `Looper` handles tasks (*Runnables, Futures*) in a thread related queue in the background - even with no user interaction or a displayed UI (app downloads a file in the background during a call).

Answer (score 3):

I will try to explain the purpose of looper class as simple as possible.
With a normal thread of Java when the run method completes the execution we say the thread has done it's job and thread lives no longer after that.
what if we want to execute more tasks throughout our program with that same thread which is not living anymore?
Oh there is a problem now right? Yes because we want to execute more tasks but the thread in not alive anymore. It is where the Looper comes in to rescue us.
Looper as the name suggests loops. Looper is nothing more than an infinite loop inside your thread. So, it keeps the thread alive for an infinite time until we explicitly calls quit() method. Calling quit() method on the infinitely alive thread will make the condition false in the infinite loop inside the thread thus, infinite loop will exit. so, the thread will die or will no longer be alive. And it's critical to call the quit() method on our Thread to which looper is attached otherwise they will be there in your system just like Zombies.
So, for example if we want to create a background thread to do some multiple tasks over it. we will create a simple Java's thread and will use Looper class to prepare a looper and attach the prepared looper with that thread so that our thread can live as longer as we want them because we can always call quit() anytime whenever we want to terminate our thread. So our the looper will keep our thread alive thus we will be able to execute multiple tasks with the same thread and when we are done we will call quit() to terminate the thread.
What if we want our Main thread or UI thread to display the results computed by the background thread or non-UI thread on some UI elements?
for that purpose there comes in the concept of Handlers;
via handlers we can do inter-process communication or say via handlers two threads can communicate with each other.
So, the main thread will have an associated Handler and Background thread will communicate with Main Thread via that handler to get the task done of displaying the results computed by it on some UI elements on Main thread.
I know I am explaining only theory here but try to understand the concept because understanding the concept in depth is very important. And I am posting a link below which will take you to a small video series about Looper, Handler and HandlerThread and I will highly recommend watching it and all these concepts will get cleared with examples there.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfLMwbOKLRk&list=PL6nth5sRD25hVezlyqlBO9dafKMc5fAU2&index=1

Answer (score 0):

I try to give an example in Kotlin. Here is below the code example.

Firstly we need to instantiate variable handler from the Handler(the provided looper instead of the default one) which ask for mainthread (Looper.getMainLooper()).

The function getAllCourses() need to return LiveData so we use handler.postDelayed() to be added to the message queque and run after x amount of millisecond specified in constant SERVICE_LATENCY_IN_MILLIS.

Please feel free to elaborate more wording to my explanation to give more clarity.

```
class RemoteDataSource private constructor(private val jsonHelper: JsonHelper) {

    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    companion object {
        private const val SERVICE_LATENCY_IN_MILLIS: Long = 2000

        @Volatile
        private var instance: RemoteDataSource? = null

        fun getInstance(helper: JsonHelper): RemoteDataSource =
                instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                    RemoteDataSource(helper).apply { instance = this }
                }
    }

    fun getAllCourses(): LiveData<ApiResponse<List<CourseResponse>>> {
        EspressoIdlingResource.increment()
        val resultCourse = MutableLiveData<ApiResponse<List<CourseResponse>>>()
        handler.postDelayed({
            resultCourse.value = ApiResponse.success(jsonHelper.loadCourses())
            EspressoIdlingResource.decrement()
        }, SERVICE_LATENCY_IN_MILLIS)
        return resultCourse
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The official way to use the Looper is in the documentation and doesn't use the deprecated Handler CTOR that has no parameters :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper

```
  class LooperThread extends Thread {
      public Handler mHandler;

      public void run() {
          Looper.prepare();

          mHandler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper()) {
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // process incoming messages here
              }
          };

          Looper.loop();
      }
  }
```

Here's an improved version of it in Kotlin that I've made:

```
open class LooperThread : Thread() {
    @Volatile
    var handler: Handler? = null
        private set

    @WorkerThread
    override fun run() {
        Looper.prepare()
        handler = object : Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!) {
            fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
                this@LooperThread.handleMessage(msg!!)
            }

        }
        Looper.loop()
    }

    @WorkerThread
    open fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
    }

    /**stops handling messages for the looper, so it can be released
     * @param quitSafely whether to use Looper.quitSafely (wait for normal messages) or Looper.quit (ditch all pending messages):
     * https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper#quitSafely()
     * https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper#quit()*/
    fun quit(quitSafely: Boolean) {
        handler?.let { handler ->
            if (quitSafely)
                handler.looper.quitSafely()
            else handler.looper.quit()
            this@LooperThread.handler = null
        }
    }
}
```