# How to properly interrupt a thread in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my application I have a button and when it gets clicked I start a new thread and change the text of button. If I press the button again it will start changing its text faster.

I would like to interrupt the thread when the button is pressed in the second time. What's the correct way to do it?

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

 Button btn;
 int i = 0;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           runThread();
       }
     });
 }

private void runThread() {
    new Thread() {
      public void run() {
          while (i++ < 1000) {
              try {
                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                          btn.setText("#" + i);
                      }
                  });
                  Thread.sleep(300);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way would be using a variable to control this.

Something like:

```
while(i++ < 1000 && keepRunning)
```

I see that as a good solution because it cant cause unexpected behavior, as you are sure the exactly moment your thread would exit.

extra--

As a suggestion, I also would recommend you to set your thread non-Damon (setDaemon(false)) because it makes layout changes

Also it is a good practice to give thread a name (setName()) to make it easy on debugging.

Comment: or he can just assign 1000 to i,

Comment: That is actually a more optimized solution, but than I recommend to create a Max variable, in case he changes it value some day and forget to change in all places.

Comment: That would make sense. Could you clarify your extra part? I didn't get it.

Comment: Yeah of course. I just wondered what would be the purpose of setting my thread as non-Demon.

Comment: If it is non-Daemon, than your thread will die with activity thread, otherwise it may still calling runOnUiThread after activity terminated.

Comment: Oh that's a great news, just what I was wondering about. Thanks

Comment: Use the build in variable in the `thread`,see `isInterrupted()`, thats a flag you can read from. Set it with calling interrupt.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, just keep a reference to your thread and use Thread.interrupt():

```
private Thread runThread() {

return new Thread() {
  public void run() {
      while (i++ < 1000) {
          try {
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      btn.setText("#" + i);
                  }
              });
              Thread.sleep(300);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Then:

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       if (myThread != null) myThread.interrupt();
       myThread = runThread();
       myThread.start();
   }
 });
```

Read this post for more info and options:

[How to properly stop the Thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java)

Comment: As far I see `keepRunning` does not have any influence, right?

Comment: copy/paste error from another answer - sorry, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Right now you start a new Thread each time you press the button.

Something like this should work.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

Button btn;
int i = 0;
Thread countThread = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
countThread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      while (i++ < 1000) {
          try {
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      btn.setText("#" + i);
                  }
              });
              Thread.sleep(300);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
 }
 btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       runThread();
   }
 });
}

private void runThread() {
  if(countThread != null) {
    if(countThread.isAlive()) {
        countThread.stop();
    } else {
        countThread.start();
    }
  }
}
```

I only had a text editor so I can't guarantee if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `thread.interrupt()` to [interrupt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Just take another variable j and it will handle your code:-

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

     Button btn;
     int i = 0,j=0;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                j=1;
               runThread();
           }
         });
     }

    private void runThread() {
        new Thread() {
          public void run() {
              while (i++ < 1000) {
                  try {
                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                          @Override
                          public void run() {
                              if(j==1){
                              btn.setText("#" + i);
                               j=0;
                               }
                                else
                                    Thread.interrupted();
                          }
                      });
                      Thread.sleep(300);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          }
        }.start();
    }
```

Comment: @user3764893, ok just use Thread.interrupted(); inside else part, i have edited my answer,just check it out....

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal [Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) in Android (and call `interrupt()` for your use case) but frameworks provides other better options by providing helper classes around Threads. You can refer to official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads.html#helper) page for other options.

[HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) is preferred option. You can call [quitSafely()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html#quitSafely()) or [quit()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html#quit()) for your use case if you go for `HandlerThread`

Related post:

[Why use HandlerThread in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712959/why-use-handlerthread-in-android)