# What is the relationship between Looper, Handler and MessageQueue in Android?

Tags: android, handler, message-queue, looper

I have checked the official Android documentation/guide for `Looper`, `Handler` and `MessageQueue` . But I couldn't get it. I am new to android, and got very confused with these concepts.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

A [`Looper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) is a message handling loop: it reads and processes items from a [`MessageQueue`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html). The `Looper` class is usually used in conjunction with a [`HandlerThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) (a subclass of `Thread`).

A [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is a utility class that facilitates interacting with a `Looper`—mainly by posting messages and `Runnable` objects to the thread's `MessageQueue`. When a `Handler` is created, it is bound to a specific `Looper` (and associated thread and message queue).

In typical usage, you create and start a `HandlerThread`, then create a `Handler` object (or objects) by which other threads can interact with the `HandlerThread` instance. The `Handler` must be created while running on the `HandlerThread`, although once created there is no restriction on what threads can use the `Handler`'s scheduling methods (`post(Runnable)`, etc.)

The main thread (a.k.a. UI thread) in an Android application is set up as a handler thread before your application instance is created.

Aside from the class docs, there's a nice discussion of all of this [here](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/).

P.S. All the classes mentioned above are in the package `android.os`.

Comment: @Ted Hopp - Is Looper’s message queue different from Thread’s message queue?

Comment: @Jack - They are the same thing. The Android [API docs for `MessageQueue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html) state that a `MessageQueue` is a "_low-level class holding the list of messages to be dispatched by a `Looper`._"

Answer (score 100):

Let's start with the Looper. You can understand the relationship between Looper, Handler and MessageQueue more easily when you understand what Looper is. Also you can better understand what Looper is in the context of GUI framework. Looper is made to do 2 things.

1) Looper **transforms a normal thread**, which terminates when its `run()` method returns, **into something that runs continuously until Android app is running**, which is needed in GUI framework (Technically, it still terminates when `run()` method returns. But let me clarify what I mean, below).

2) Looper **provides a queue** where jobs to be done are enqueued, which is also needed in GUI framework.

As you may know, when an application is launched, the system creates a thread of execution for the application, called “main”, and Android applications normally run entirely on a single thread by default the “main thread”. But **main thread is not some secret, special thread**. It's just a normal thread that you can also create with `new Thread()` code, which means it terminates when its `run()` method returns! Think of below example.

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
    }
}
```

Now, let's apply this simple principle to Android app. What would happen if an Android app is run on a normal thread? A thread called "main" or "UI" or whatever starts application, and draws all UI. So, the first screen is displayed to users. So what now? The main thread terminates? No, it shouldn’t. It should wait until users do something, right? But how can we achieve this behavior? Well, we can try with `Object.wait()` or `Thread.sleep()`. For example, main thread finishes its initial job to display first screen, and sleeps. It awakes, which means interrupted, when a new job to do is fetched. So far so good, but at this moment we need a queue-like data structure to hold multiple jobs. Think about a case when a user touches screen serially, and a task takes longer time to finish. So, we need to have a data structure to hold jobs to be done in first-in-first-out manner. Also, you may imagine, implementing ever-running-and-process-job-when-arrived thread using interrupt is not easy, and leads to complex and often unmaintainable code. We'd rather create a new mechanism for such purpose, and ***that is what Looper is all about***. The [official document of Looper class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) says, "Threads by default do not have a message loop associated with them", and Looper is a class "used to run a message loop for a thread". Now you can understand what it means.

Let's move to Handler and MessageQueue. First, MessageQueue is the queue that I mentioned above. It resides inside a Looper, and that's it. You can check it with [Looper class's source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Looper.java). Looper class has a member variable of MessageQueue.

Then, what is Handler? If there is a queue, then there should be a method that should enable us to enqueue a new task to the queue, right? That is what Handler does. We can enqueue a new task into a queue(MessageQueue) using various `post(Runnable r)` methods. That's it. This is all about Looper, Handler, and MessageQueue.

My last word is, so basically Looper is a class that is made to address a problem that occurs in GUI framework. But this kind of needs also can happen in other situations as well. Actually it is a pretty famous pattern for multi threads application, and you can learn more about it in "Concurrent Programming in Java" by Doug Lea(Especially, chapter 4.1.4 "Worker Threads" would be helpful). Also, you can imagine this kind of mechanism is not unique in Android framework, but all GUI frameworks may need somewhat similar to this. You can find almost same mechanism in Java Swing framework.

Comment: Best answer. Learned more from this detailed explanation. I wonder if there is some blog post which goes in more detail.

Comment: Can the messages be added to the MessageQueue without using Handler?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad no they can't be  added directly.

Comment: Made my day...lots of love to you :)

Answer (score 99):

It's widely known that it's illegal to **update UI components** directly from threads other than **main thread** in android. This android document ([Handling Expensive Operations in the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#threading)) suggests the steps to follow if we need to start a separate thread to do some **expensive work** and update UI after it's done. The idea is to create a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) object associated with **main thread**, and post a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) to it at appropriate time. This `Runnable` will be invoked on the **main thread**. This mechanism is implemented with [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) and [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) classes.

The `Looper` class maintains a [MessageQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html), which contains a list [messages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html). An important character of Looper is that it's **associated** with the **thread within which the `Looper` is created**. This association is **kept forever** and can't be broken nor changed. Also note that a thread **can't be associated with more than** one `Looper`. In order to guarantee this association, `Looper` is stored in thread-local storage, and it can't be created via its constructor directly. The only way to create it is to call [prepare](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#prepare%28%29) static method on `Looper`. prepare method first examines [ThreadLocal](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) of current thread to make sure that there isn't already a Looper associated with the thread. After the examination, a new `Looper` is created and saved in `ThreadLocal`. Having prepared the `Looper`, we can call [loop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#loop%28%29) method on it to check for new messages and have `Handler` to deal with them.

As the name indicates, the `Handler` class is mainly responsible for handling (adding, removing, dispatching) messages of current thread's `MessageQueue`. A `Handler` instance is also bound to a thread. The **binding between Handler and Thread** is achieved via `Looper` and `MessageQueue`. A `Handler` is **always bound to** a `Looper`, and subsequently bound to the **thread associated** with the `Looper`. Unlike `Looper`, multiple Handler instances can be bound to the same thread. Whenever we call [post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or any methods alike on the `Handler`, a new message is added to the associated `MessageQueue`. The target field of the message is set to current `Handler` instance. When the `Looper` received this message, it invokes [dispatchMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#dispatchMessage%28android.os.Message%29) on message's target field, so that the message routes back to to the Handler instance to be handled, but on the correct thread. 
The relationships between `Looper`, `Handler` and `MessageQueue` is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! but whats the point if the handler first **post** the message to the message queue and then **handle** the message from the same queue? why doesn't it just handle the message directly?

Comment: @Blake b/c you are posting from one thread (non looper thread) but handling the message in another thread(looper thread)

Comment: Much better than what's being documented on https://developer.android.com - but it would be nice to see code for the diagram that you've provided.

Comment: @numansalati - Can’t Handler post messages from the looper thread?

Comment: A single vote can't justify the appreciation this answer deserves :(

Answer (score 28):

`MessageQueue`: It is a low-level class holding the list of messages to be dispatched by a `Looper`. Messages are not added directly to a `MessageQueue`, but rather through `Handler` objects associated with the `Looper`.[[3](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html)]

`Looper`: It loops over a `MessageQueue` which contains the messages to be dispatched. The actual task of managing the queue is done by the `Handler` which is responsible for handling (adding, removing, dispatching) messages in the message queue.[[2](http://riteattitude.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-ui-thread.html)]

`Handler`: It allows you to send and process `Message` and `Runnable` objects associated with a thread's `MessageQueue`. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue.[[4](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)]

When you create a new `Handler`, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, **it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue** and **execute them as they come out of the message queue**.

Kindly, go through the below image[[2](http://riteattitude.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-ui-thread.html)] for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer, by @K_Anas, with an example,
As it stated

> **It's widely known that it's illegal to update UI components directly from threads other than main thread in android.**

for instance if you try to update the UI using Thread.

```
    int count = 0;
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    sleep(1000);
                    count++;
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


   ).start();
```

your app will crash with exception.

> android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

in other words you need to use `Handler` which keeps reference to the `MainLooper`  i.e. `Main Thread` or `UI Thread` and pass task as `Runnable`.

```
  Handler handler = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper);
        int count = 0;
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while(true) {
                        sleep(1000);
                        count++;
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                                 textView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                           }
                         });

                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    ).start() ;
```