# Can this be garbage-collected?

Tags: android, runnable

In existing (presumably) working code I see the following construct:

```
void someFunc() {

    some_irrelevant_code();

    new Runnable() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            //will run each 5 seconds
            doSomething();

            if (!needStopSomeThread)
            {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }
        }
    }.run();
}
```

I wonder if the Runnable and the Handler may be garbage-collected at an arbitrary moment. It looks like only the runnable references the handler, and only the handler references the runnable, so they may be both garbage-collected, unless Android has a data structure referencing one of them, e.g. the handler.

1) Can they both (the handler and the runnable) get garbage-collected?

2) If they can get garbage-collected, how can I prove it actually happens?

Comment: I believe the answer to your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14601968/1127492

Comment: @Stefan: so, can they be both garbage-collected? (I do not see how it may follow from that link.)

Comment: See the code of the LooperThread (in the answer mentioned above), how to use the handler in a Thread. If the looper thread is terminated an can be gc'ed so can the handler.

Comment: @Stefan you mean that if the looper thread is not explicitly terminated (and it does not terminate implicitly), it will reference the handler, and, consequently, the runnable. Right?

Comment: Yes. The thread usually is implicitly terminated when the activity or the service terminates.