# Android Service :upload image to a http server

Tags: android, service, upload, broadcastreceiver, httpserver

I'm trying to upload image from my android phone to a http server, in a service.
Well i have a brodcastreceiver in an activity ,and every time there is data ,it send it to the service to do the upload. But ,my code just do only one upload (i cheks it in the server ) then crashes (withote any error message ).

I hope someone can tell me the reason of the crash ,and thank you in advance.

**PS**:my doubts are in the Looper.prepare(); and Looper.loop(); i'm not very familiar to them ,even after reading about them.

**This my onStartCommand of my Service :**

```
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service started 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int rssi1 = intent.getIntExtra("key1", 0);
        int rssi2 = intent.getIntExtra("key2", 0);
        int rssi3 = intent.getIntExtra("key3", 0);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service started 2" + rssi1 +" "+ rssi2 + " " + rssi3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service Appel 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.1.150:8080/UploadToServer.php";
            mContext = getApplicationContext();
          folder = new File("/storage/sdcard");
          new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {   Looper.prepare();
                    imagepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile1.jpg";
                    uploadFile(imagepath);

                }
            }).start();
          Looper.loop();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: What did you do at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the `Looper.prepare();` and `Looper.loop();`. You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do the upload task in a worker thread. Like this:

```
class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Object, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... content) {
        uploadFile(content[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in the service:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    imagepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile1.jpg";
    new UploadTask().execute(imagepath, null, null);
}
```

PS: You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877944/what-is-the-relationship-between-looper-handler-and-message-queue) to get yourself familiar with Looper and Handler stuff.

Answer (score 1):

then i believe ur problem is not uploading since one image is uploaded...

since u r trying to upload and its not UI task wat u can do is remove the service and do it in tbe BroadCastReceiver(BCR) itself... whenever there is receive called in BCR u can try to upload...

Also to me the crash is due to continous running of the thread i think after uploading ur removing the image so may be its crashing for dat reason but dats my guess so at first u try to upload in BCR itself after dat when u r okay then for service u can do place a flag which will say if new file has come  or not then only run the uploading function dat flag can be a public static boolean of BCR which u can access in service..

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @user1915922 , intresting tip of the flag, i'll try it.