# How do Threads, Handler and Loopers Work together?

Tags: android, multithreading, threadpool, android-handler, android-looper

Forgive me if i make a mistake but I'm really new to this particular topic and i need a clear understanding with the help of an example from Android's context

Threads are processes working separately from the main thread. 
Loopers are used for storing tasks like a pipeline.
Handlers pass tasks to Loopers.

I know i could be wrong in defining these and this is the reason I've asked this question.

I read a lot of questions and articles but couldn't figure out what these three classes ( actually 2)  are for and how do they work and how can I implement them in an application. 
These are some of the questions making me stuck.

Where do we use each one of them? 
When and Where to use them? 
How to use them together? 
With an Example?

It's a request please don't mark it as a broad question i really need to know what they are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the relationship between Looper, Handler and Message queue ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877944/what-is-the-relationship-between-looper-handler-and-message-queue)

Comment: Please learn to search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597742/what-is-the-purpose-of-looper-and-how-to-use-it

Comment: Mike M. Thank you I'll keep that in mind