# Do we need invoking Looper.prepare() when invoking Handler

Tags: android, multithreading, android-looper

I need to understand about the *Looper*. Looper will consult appropiate *handler* to to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue.

*By default, a thread does not have a message loop associated with it*, hence doesn’t have a Looper either. To create a Looper for a thread and dedicate that thread to process messages serially from a message loop, you can use the Looper class.

The following is my code I don't invoke Looper explicitly

```
Thread background2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

            for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
               final int v =i;
                    try {   Thread.sleep(1000);
                  handler.post(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                        txt.setText(txt.getText() +  "Thread 2 current i : " + String.valueOf(v) +System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                     }
                  });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.v("Error", e.toString());
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Does it mean that the task/runnable is not put in the queue? what's the difference of above code with this

```
Thread background3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
     Looper.prepare();
            for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
               final int v =i;
                    try {   Thread.sleep(1000);
                  handler.post(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                        txt.setText(txt.getText()+ "Thread 3 set : " + String.valueOf(v) +System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                     }
                  });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.v("Error", e.toString());
                    }
                }
Looper.loop();
            }
        });
```

both of them accessing a *same handler*. They both work fine.

Comment: A `Thread` does not need a `Looper` to post to another `Thread`'s `Handler`, if that's what you're asking. The `Handler`s in your examples are for other `Thread`s, whichever `Thread`s you're creating them on.

Comment: Hello, I'm confused now so what's the difference on my second example, there I'm invoking Looper.prepare( ) explicitly, but without it, it still works

Comment: Creating a `Looper` for a `Thread` means that _other_ `Thread`s can post to it. The `Looper` in your example isn't really doing anything, since you're not posting anything to a `Handler` created there, which is why you don't see a difference.

Comment: Mike, whats `that other Threads can post to it` in this context?? could you put it as answer please,

Comment: Well, there are plenty of answers here that already cover this, so I'd rather find a duplicate than post a repeat answer. Anyway, in your second example, since you're starting a `Looper` in that `Thread`, you could create a `Handler` for that `Looper`, pass it to another `Thread`, and then that other `Thread` can post to it. Your example `Thread`s are posting `Runnable`s to whichever other `Thread` the `Handler`s are created for. They're not posting them to themselves.

Comment: Think of a `Thread` as a neighborhood, a `Looper` as a post office, and a `Handler` as a mailman from that post office. If a neighborhood (`Thread`) doesn't have a post office (`Looper`), you can't send letters there. If it does have a post office (`Looper`), then you can send letters to that neighborhood (`Thread`), but you have to use their mailman (`Handler`).

Comment: No problem. I'll try to find a duplicate that explains it well.

Comment: These two have some pretty good explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877944/what-is-the-relationship-between-looper-handler-and-messagequeue-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597742/what-is-the-purpose-of-looper-and-how-to-use-it Don't get discouraged. It can take a little while to get a grasp on this stuff.

Comment: Ok Mike thanks for helping me I'll patiently understanding this. and read the posts you posted.

Comment: Actually, I was just thinking, now that I reread those other answers, they don't really directly address your particular question or situation. I think I will put together an answer for you, to better explain than I can in comments. Gimme a little bit.

Comment: Okay just take time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a `Looper` for a `Thread` means you're setting up that `Thread` to receive messages from other `Thread`s. Both of your examples are behaving exactly the same because the you're not sending anything to the `Thread` in the second example. That is, the `background3`'s `Looper` isn't really being used.

In both examples, you're posting a `Runnable` to a `Handler` that was created for the main `Thread`'s `Looper`. You're not creating that `Handler` for, e.g., `background2`. That `Handler` belongs to the main `Thread` and its `Looper`, and anything you post to it will be put into the main queue, and run on the main `Thread`.

The only difference in your examples is that the second `Thread` has a `Looper`, and you *could* post to it, if you wanted to. To do that, you would create another `Handler` that belonged to `background3`'s `Looper`, and post to that. You're not doing that, though, so the second `Thread` just continues to run without doing anything else.

A `Thread` doesn't need a `Looper` simply to post to *another* `Thread`'s Handler, which is really all that your examples are doing. That other `Thread` - the main `Thread`, in this case - has already prepared and started its `Looper`. You're just sending `Runnable`s to it, and you don't need a `Looper` of your own to do that.

Comment: Lemme know if I didn't adequately explain anything.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike I get it know. The other posts you posted on the comment explains Looper too general as a kind of manager thread. But your answer is making it clear .