# Is there a PostMessage equivalent for use in Java/Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

So my Android app has a couple of threads that I have sitting in a loop, using sleep to keep from running non-stop.  I would love to be able to send a message in between threads, or notifications if that's a better term.

Is there something I can use like Windows messages?  I'm even thinking can each thread have a button, that isn't displayed and that I could send a notification to?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the relationship between Looper, Handler and MessageQueue in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877944/what-is-the-relationship-between-looper-handler-and-messagequeue-in-android)

Comment: use `android.os.Handler` for `Message` sending between threads

Answer (score 0):

Today I think the recommended way today is to use a [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

To get something akin to the `PostMessage` method in the .net world, you could use a `Handler`, like described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html).

Answer (score -1):

you can implement Looper and use them.
These might help you.
[Looper.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html)
also below sample
[inter thread communication](http://techtej.blogspot.in/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html)

Answer (score -1):

Thread notifier will help you for this.

please try with below link
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-the-wait-and-notify-methods.html