# Message sent to the UI thread never arrives

Tags: java, android, multithreading

This topic has been discussed many times so far, but still haven't managed got it working.

My `MainActivity` has a property called `Handler mHandlerUi;` which is initialized in its constructor

```
mHandlerUi = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                onMessageArrive(msg);
            }
        };
```

Later on in the code, In another class, during construction time i initialize another Handler property

`mHandlerToUi = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());`

So during the thread's life time, the following code snippet is executed X times.

```
    Message msg = mHandlerToUi.obtainMessage();
    msg.what = ConstMessages.MSG_NEW_GPS_POINT;
    msg.setData(bundleContet);

    mHandlerToUi.sendMessage(msg);
```

Unfortunately the message never arrives the MainActivity's Looper, Both threads uses the same UI's looper,

What am i missing over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have initiated two handlers and you want to pass the message from one to another?

Perhaps you should pass the handler to the second class instead. So in your `MainActivity` you have

```
mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {
            onMessageArrive(msg);
        }
    }
```

and pass this `mHandler` to your second class via constructor or setter method.

Comment: This exactly what I'm trying to do, but how come i need to share Handler's reference among the classes, and not its looper? Is there a way to achieve same effect is if i would use DuplicateHandle(c language)

Comment: Kevinrob has answered your question, what stops you from passing the handler reference?

Answer (score 1):

Each `Handler` handle its messages. The `Looper` is used for running a `Handler` on a specific `Thread`.

If you create two `Handler`, there will not communicate. There will only share the same `Looper` that run on a `Thread`.

You can find good answers on [What is the relationship between Looper, Handler and MessageQueue in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877944/what-is-the-relationship-between-looper-handler-and-messagequeue-in-android)

Comment: So Looper is just the queue management among other instances, but communication itself is done by the Handler?

Comment: @igalk read [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a)