# How to get Executor for main thread on API level < 28

Tags: android, multithreading, android-context, executor

On API level 28(Pie) a new method is introduced in the `Context` class to get Executor for the main thread [`getMainExecutor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getMainExecutor()).

How to get this executor on API level below 28?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use (in activity for example):

```
ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat.html#getMainExecutor(android.content.Context)

Answer (score 12):

You can use code snippet from retrofit https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Platform.java

```
public class MainThreadExecutor implements Executor {
    private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override 
    public void execute(Runnable r) {
        handler.post(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) Right! there was a reason why `Executor` is just an interface, **allowing it's implements (instead of searching all over for it in different API).**

Answer (score 9):

You can use `new HandlerExecutor(Looper.getMainLooper());` from `com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.HandlerExecutor`...in the end it's the same answer as [atarasenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5312102/atarasenko).

I added an extension in Kotlin for that:

```
fun Context.mainExecutor(): Executor {
    return if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.P) {
        mainExecutor
    } else {
        HandlerExecutor(mainLooper)
    }
}
```