# getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread must have a looper

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, android-looper

I am getting this error, and my application crashes:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread must have a looper!

I didn't get much about how to use looper on Google, I am using threads(mainly for sleep function), handler(for downloading the image while Async task is running) and Async task(for getting the JSON data from the URL). I have no idea how to resolve this issue, so any suggestions will be vey helpful.

This is the code for the thread which is executed on click of the button:

```
View view = flingContainer.getSelectedView();
          view.findViewById(R.id.item_swipe_right_indicator).setAlpha((float) 1.0);

        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(320);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectLeft();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
```

I am using [this](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards) libray and log-cat is:
[image]

where: `at com.enormous.quotesgram.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:479)` in last in log-cat corresponds to the line: `flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectLeft();` in above piece of code.

Comment: update with code and logcat plz

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597742/what-is-the-purpose-of-looper-and-how-to-use-it

Comment: @Keshav1234: there are tons of good documentations about `Looper`'s. IMHO the question is: why does the method above expect the current thread to be a `Looper`? (here some nice docs about `Looper`'s: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/; http://mobilengineering.blogspot.de/2012/12/threading-loopers-and-messaging-queues.html; http://codetheory.in/android-handlers-runnables-loopers-messagequeue-handlerthread/)

Comment: Hello brother your post clearly states you did not get how to use looper in google hence that link was referred. Please check your question twice before posting.

Comment: @Keshav1234: I was afraid that your link might not be helpful as it refers rather to a newly created Looper thread. In this case OP needs most likely to use the already existing UI thread (from the links above: _"The most prominent usage of Pipeline Thread is found within almost any UI framework, including .... Android Activities."_).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (unfortunately I cannot test the code):

```
Thread timer = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(320);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectLeft();
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

The idea behind is, that the `Timer` thread is *not* a `Looper` thread (resulting in an exception saying *"The current thread must have a looper"*). The UI thread however, is a `Looper` thread (see for instance [this site](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/)).

As `flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectLeft()` is probably designed to run on the UI thread it fails, if it not invoked in side of a pipelined thread.