# A queue of background tasks in rxjava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

Is it possible to implement a queue of background tasks using rxjava? 
I need possibility to add task at any time and only one tasks executed simultaneously. I have tried `PublishSubject`, but when i'm pushing execution to the new thread `observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` it starts more than one task at time.

**UPDATE:** 
Is it possible to implement something like producer-consumer pattern using rxjava?

Comment: MightySeal please hava look at Looper in android http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

Comment: @Fasiha how will it help?

Comment: pleas see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597742/what-is-the-purpose-of-looper-and-how-to-use-it

Comment: @Fasiha it's not about the solution and not about rxjava. Actually I'm new to rxjava and looking for producer-consumer alike pattern implementation.

Comment: ok so you need something like mutex lock or semaphore?

Comment: @Fasiha nope, it's all about reactive paradigm.

Comment: RxJava isn't replace-everything-with-it framework. It's just a library. Use `BlockingQueue`, `Executors`, `Services` or what you were using before to create a queue of background tasks and then use `Observable` to describe what operation task is.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I'm also trying to implement message queue using RxJava

Comment: @AntonShkurenko unfotunately no, i've just implemented producer-consumer using rx for multithreading. However i was thinking of using PublishSubject for the queue and using map operator to emit new observables.

Answer (score 8):

Just use a scheduler based on a single thread executor:

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
observable.observeOn(scheduler). ...
```