# How to make a periodic code run off the UI thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, runnable, ui-thread

The following code is what I'm using currently, but there is an issue that the Toast is being shown, so it probably is in the UI thread isn't it? I do not want the run() function to run on the UI thread as I will probably add some heavy downloading there. However, I want to repeatedly execute this code (after every 9000ms) So what must I do, to either make this run off the UI thread, or a solution to my problem. Thank you.

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Thread feedthread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            Toast.makeText(context, "UI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 9000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(feedthread, 9000);
```

Please do not suggest AsyncTask to me unless there is a way to repeat the code without using a while loop wasting resources or setting the thread to sleep. I would like answers to what I asked, and I **do not** want to run the code on the UI thread.

Comment: You can use AsyncTask instead of Thread, it has callbacks for this UI stuff.

Comment: why do you call `postDelayed` with a `Thread` object ?

Comment: I want to run the runnable at a later time, and I want it to run asynchronously, hence I delayed the post of a new thread. If this is the wrong way, please help me on which is right. I would prefer not to use async tasks or setting the thread to sleep

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the *runOnUiThread* method to show the Toast

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Thread feedthread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, "UI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        handler.postDelayed(this, 9000);
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(feedthread, 9000);
```

Comment: I DON'T want to show the toast, I don't want the code to run on the UI thread, and the toast was just to check if it does.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class. Here is an example to show how it works:

```
// Async Task Class
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    // (Optional) Runs on the UI thread before the background task starts
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Do some UI stuff if needed
    }

    // Runs on a background thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
        String url = param[0];
        // Do something with the param, like kick off a download
        // You can also use publishProgress() here if desired at regular intervals
        /*while (isDownloading) {
            publishProgress("" + progress);
        }*/
        return null;
    }

    // (Optional) Runs on the UI thread periodically during the background task via publishProgress()
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // Update UI to show progress
        /* prgDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0])); */
    }

    // (Optional) Runs on the UI thread after the background task completes
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // Do some UI stuff to show completion of the task (if needed)
    }
}
```

You can run your task like this:

```
String url = getInternetUrl();
new MyTask().execute(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java Thread

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    private boolean stopped = false;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!stopped) {    
            // Do, do, do...
            try {
                Thread.Sleep(9000);
            } catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
}).start();
```

---

### Android Handler

Also you can use Android handler class to run a code periodically. This requires you to have a looper-prepared thread to attach the handler to. Basically, a looper-prepared thread is assign a queue and every message posted to this thread will be queued and processed one by one in a queue manner.

This approach has a difference with the former one and is that if your do a lot of work in that background thread so that takes some time, then subsequent queued messages will be processed quicker than the interval (in this case, 9 seconds). Because looper-enabled threads immediately process the next queued message, once they are done with the previous one.

[Find More Info Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597742/what-is-the-purpose-of-looper-and-how-to-use-it)

---

**Note:** You shouldn't [and can't] use this approach as an alternative to Service. This newly created thread does need an underlying component (either Activity or Service) to keep it alive.

Comment: All I was advised is, to not use Thread.sleep and instead use postdelayed as thread sleep keeps the resources alive until it wakes up again, I don't know properly. But if there is a disadvantage to thread.sleep, please could you edit the code to have delayed post by a handler?