# Is this an example of redundant use of Handlers?

Tags: java, android, handler, looper

Is there any point in having multiple Handlers if they use the same Looper?

eg:

```
private Handler firstHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private Handler secondHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
firstHandler.post(...);
secondHandler.post(...);
```

... they both post to the main thread, is that pointless to have the second one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this an example of redundant use of Handlers?

Yes.

Quoted from the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler):

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects
>   associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is
>   associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When
>   you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of
>   the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver
>   messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they
>   come out of the message queue.

Those Handlers are sending messages to the same `MessageQueue`, so anyway the second one will run after the first one is done, meaning it's redundant.

Further more, The `Handler` is associated with the `Thread` it's created in by default. So if the `Handler` is created on the `main thread` you don't have to specify a Looper.

Answer (score 0):

Yes both handlers are pointing to same `"MessageQueue"`. More information can be had from the following link:

[What is the purpose of Looper and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597742/what-is-the-purpose-of-looper-and-how-to-use-it)