# Anonymous runnable implementation and posting it to a handler

Tags: java, android

I know handler attached to a main thread runs on main thread.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


        }, DELAY_MS);
```

In the above does the run method actually gets executed on a different back-round thread.

Comment: I made some edits

Answer (score 0):

No this will just get executed on the `MainThread`.

**Why?**
Because the `Runnable` you are creating is queued inside the `Loopers MessageQueue (can contain Runnables or` [other things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597742/what-is-the-purpose-of-looper-and-how-to-use-it) ) which will be processed sequentially. If you want to get a deeper understanding there was already [a great question about the Looper asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597742/what-is-the-purpose-of-looper-and-how-to-use-it)