# Android UI Thread Rendering Worker Thread

Tags: android, rendering, ui-thread, worker-thread

> Android uses MessageQueue (pipeline thread pattern) to process UI
>   events (such as button clicks, mouse movement, orientation changes,
>   screen redraw and so on). This allows you to change a button caption
>   without having to worry that the user will click the button at the
>   same moment.
>
> But when we post Message to worker thread MessageQueue ([which is different with UI Thread MessageQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704513/android-messagequeue))

**How the Rendering happen?**

> I mean to say we can perform rendering only on UI thread then how it
>   is possible with worker thread too.

Please correct me if I am wrong...

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding.

We cannot directly update the UI from the worker thread. But, we can follow a series of steps as suggested in android document to update the contents of UI from a worker thread.

1. Create a `Handler` object associated with main thread
2. Post a `Runnable` to the main thread from the worker thread at appropriate time.

This Runnable will be invoked on the main thread. This mechanism is implemented with `Looper and Handler classes.`

Please feel free to add to the answer.

Comment: .@Prem We can create a Handler which can be associated with worker thread too. In that case Message (Runnable) will be executed on worker thread

Comment: If you do that, then you are accessing the UI from a non-UI thread. This may work under some circumstances, but is explicitly not allowed.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I strongly agree with you...thanks!