# Why does Looper.loop() not block the UI thread

Tags: android, handler, android-looper

This is the code in ActivityThread.main():

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ......

        Looper.prepareMainLooper();

        ...

        Looper.loop();

        throw new RuntimeException("Main thread loop unexpectedly exited");
    }
```

It made the Looper running. There is a loop running in the Looper.loop() all the time. Why does Looper.loop() not block the UI thread?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why main thread's Looper.loop() doesn't block UI thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931899/why-main-threads-looper-loop-doesnt-block-ui-thread)

Comment: No. I saw it before post the question.

Answer (score 4):

`Looper.loop()` prepares the `Looper` to run the messages that are passed to the thread.

It doesn't blindly keep iterating over itself, rather it uses a `MessageQueue` to listen for messages and runs them.

It's an event driven methodology, where the `Looper` is prepared to loop and run the messages when the `MessageQueue` notifies it that it contains messages. To know more about how
android event loop works, take a look at this [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20160310145528/https://mattias.niklewski.com/2012/09/android_event_loop.html).
[image: Looper.looop()]

([source](https://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2013/09/android-looper-and-toast-from.html))