# android bulletproof toast method

Tags: android, multithreading, service, toast

My application has many classes, worker threads, and background service operations. Notifications can come in from those other threads and they can come in on a service when the app isn't running. I have a utility class where I would like to write a single "SendToast(Context ctx, String message)" method that can handle all of these situations. Is it possible? [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread) comes close, but it won't work for my service messages

```
// won't work.. I need something that can run given a Context, rather than
// an Activity
public static void ShowToast(final Activity activity, 
    final String message, int length) {
       activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
       Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from the Android Design Patterns site: "Dialogs and toasts are for feedback not notification. Your app should not create a dialog or toast if it is not currently on screen".

See: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

Use a Notification instead.

Comment: OK. Good point. I could do that, but I thought it would be nice to have toasts come up just in case the user was looking at the screen when the message came in. They are a little less intrusive than task-bar notifications, and in some cases that may be preferable. Any chance it could still be done (even though the android big-wigs say not to), or is it just a bad idea and I should give it up?