# Toast from a Non-UI thread

Tags: android, toast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Toast in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread)

I am calling a helper class function from a worker thread, wherein I am trying to raise a toast but I am getting following exception

```
Android Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare
```

Can't we raise a toast from a Non UI thread ?

Comment: You can't do that. Sorry.
You must call to a UI thread to show a Toast

Comment: Why you do not use Google before posting this question?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `runOnUiThread()` For example

`this.runOnUiThread(show_toast);`

and in `show_toast`

```
private Runnable show_toast = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        Toast.makeText(Autoamtion.this, "My Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
    }
};
```