# Android: When should I use a Handler() and when should I use a Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

When I need something to run *asynchronously*, such as a **long running task** or a logic that uses the network, or for whatever reason,
Starting a **new Thread** and running it works fine.
Creating a **Handler** and running it works as well.
What's the difference? When should I use each one?
What are the advantages / reasons to use a `Handler` and not a `Thread`?

PS.
- For this question's sake, let's ignore `AsyncTask`.
- `Handler().postDelayed` use case is clear to me, for this question's sake let's assume I need the task to start immediately.

Comment: In your situation just go straight ahead and use a new Thread, my next suggestion would be AsyncTask but that is not what you want clearly. Handlers are mostly used if you want to add a delay or some other type of customization to a runnable.

Comment: @kabuto178 well, there are other benefits of the handlers worth mentioning that you skipped. Such as, being able to interact with the UI thread from a separate thread..

Answer (score 187, accepted):

If whatever you are doing is "heavy" you should be doing it in a Thread. If you do not explicitly start it in its own thread, then it will run on the main (UI) thread which may be noticeable as jittery or slow to respond interface by your users.

Interestingly when you are using a thread it is often useful to also use a Handler as a means of communication between the work thread that you are starting and the main thread.

A typical Thread/Handler interaction might look something like this:

```
Handler h = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        if(msg.what == 0){
            updateUI();
        }else{
            showErrorDialog();
        }
    }
};

Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        doSomeWork();
        if(succeed){
            //we can't update the UI from here so we'll signal our handler and it will do it for us.
            h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }else{
            h.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        }
    }   
};
```

In general though, the take home is that you should use a Thread any time you are doing some work that could be long running or very intensive (i.e. anything network, file IO, heavy arithmatic, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the amount of time invested (and the speed of your reply!!)!  So, let me see if I got this: Handler is designed to facilitate non-blocking communication between worker threads and the UI thread?

Comment: @JRun That is one of the uses yes. [Check out the Handler description in the java docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for some great info about it. Including another of its uses (to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future).

Comment: nicely explained @FoamyGuy !

Comment: Hi, is it guaranteed that `updateUI()` will run after `onCreateView` (after new views are loaded)?

Comment: Can multiple threads report back to the same Handler?  If so, how is that done?

Comment: Why is it `message.what()`? Wouldn't it just be `if(msg == 0){`? Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 81):

Handler and Thread are really 2 different things.

A thread must be created to execute long running jobs.

A Handler is very convenient object to communicate between 2 threads (for instance : a background thread need to update the UI. You can use a Handler to post some Runnable from your background thread to the UI thread).

So you don't have the choice between Handler or Thread. Use a thread to do heavy jobs! (you can use a Handler if your background thread will trigger some job to be done in another thread - most of the time the UI thread)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the amount of time invested (and the speed of your reply!!)!

Answer (score 34):

`Handler` and `Thread` are two different things, but they do not contradict each other. You can have a `Handler` and a `Thread` at the same time and actually each `Handler` must be running in a `Thread`.

For more details, you may want to [check out this article](http://pierrchen.blogspot.com.au/2015/08/android-concurrent-programming-looper.html).

[image]

Answer (score 21):

A `Handler` runs on the same `Thread`, a `Thread` runs on a different thread.

*Use a Handler if you need to run something on the same thread*, usually a GUI element or something like that.

*Use a Thread if you want to keep the main thread free to do other things*. Use this for anything that takes a significant amount of time.

Comment: why should i use a handler if i want to run something on the same thread? what is the purpose of the mHandler.post(...) method?

Comment: Elias, in such a case, you might use the handler if you want for a certain task to run after a certain amount of time, or to repeat a task every X amount of time. If you do not want to use these things, you are right. it is unworthy to use a handler. you can just do the GUI things right there and then, bcoz you are in the UI thread anyhow, because the handler runs on the thread in which it was created.

Answer (score 17):

Handlers are the best way of communication between the background and UI thread. Generally Handlers are associated with message Queue of a Thread and they are used to send messages and runnable to the Message.

**USE:**

**Thread:** To do tasks in saperate(Background) thread than UI thread. (helps to unblock the UI thread)

**Handler** Used to communicate between the UI and Background thread.

Have a look at this [article](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a)

Answer (score 4):

> If you need to update the user interface from a new Thread, you need
>   to synchronize with the user interface thread.
>
> You can use the android.os.Handler class or the AsyncTasks class for
>   this.
>
> The Handler class can update the user interface. A Handler provides
>   methods for receiving instances of the Message or Runnable class.
>
> You thread can post messages via the sendMessage(Message msg) method
>   or via the sendEmptyMessage() method.

... more info [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) about threads etc. (includes turorials for the different threading and sync mechanisms and when to use what)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I love Lars Vogel's blog, it is very insightful and easy to follow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> What are the advantages / reasons to use a Handler and not a Thread?

A [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) allows you to send and process Message and `Runnable` objects associated with a thread's `MessageQueue`. Each `Handler` instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue.

When you create a new `Handler`, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

There are two main uses for a Handler:

1. To schedule messages and *Runnables* to be executed as some point in the future
2. To *enqueue* an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

If you use java threads, you have to handle somethings on your own - synchronizing with main thread, cancelling a thread etc.

This single Thread does not create a thread pool unless you use `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `ExecutorService` API.

(Taken this query from your comments on Blackbelt answer)

> Why not use an Executor? and even if I did want to use a Handler to do that, how?

Reference : [Thread Performance article](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads.html)

There are certain types of work that can be reduced to highly parallel, distributed tasks. With the sheer volume of work packets this creates, `AsyncTask` and `HandlerThread` aren’t appropriate classes. The single-threaded nature of `AsyncTask` would turn all the threadpooled work into a linear system. Using the `HandlerThread` class, on the other hand, would require the programmer to manually manage load balancing between a group of threads.

[ThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) is a helper class to make this process easier. This class manages the creation of a group of threads, sets their priorities, and manages how work is distributed among those threads. As workload increases or decreases, the class spins up or destroys more threads to adjust to the workload.

```
 BlockingQueue workQueue= new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100); // Work pool size
 ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(),       // Initial pool size
            Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(),       // Max pool size
            1, // KEEP_ALIVE_TIME
            TimeUnit.SECONDS, //  KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT
            workQueue);
```

You can refer to this developer guide article on [create-threadpool](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html) for more details.

Have a look at this post for usage of `Handler` to run multiple Runnable instances. In this case, all `Runnable` tasks will run in a single Thread.

[Android: Toast in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread/45922317#45922317)

Answer (score 1):

`Handler` can be used in conjunction with `Thread` in order to create a Queued mechanism. Uou can use the `handler` to post something on the `Thread` `Looper`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Why not use an Executor? and even if I did want to use a Handler to do that, how?

Comment: executor  is a bit different. In order to use it you have to extend thread and in the run call the static.metohd prepare.of the Looper class. after you call the static method loop a queue is created and you can use an handlerbin order to forward requestes and get results back

Answer (score 0):

If you have to execute a task only once separately outside main thread, then use Thread. If you want to execute tasks repeatedly then android provides a way to keep threads alive and receive the messages or Runnable objects to process them using Looper in a MessageQueue.