# how to pass function to another class and call if from there in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

i want to have a function in one class, 
that does an animation and then notify''s a function that is passed to it which is in another class. 
how do i do that ?

exapmle:
in my scanning barcode activity i have:

```
 public void callbackFNC () {
    //this is the callback bunction
}
```

from scanning barcode activity i'm calling a function that is in another activity like (i want to pass the callback that is in scanning barcode activity as parameter there) :

```
loadToastModule loadToastMD = new loadToastModule();
loadToastMD.doEvent(toastModel);
```

then in doEvent that sits in LoadToastModule.class function i want to have

```
public void doEvent(LoadToast toastModel) {
        toastModel.error();



        new CountDownTimer(0, 500) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //do nothing
            }

            public void onFinish() {

               ****DO THE CALLBACK HERE
               ****DO THE CALLBACK HERE

            }
        }.start();
```

- it is important to me that i'll use it like this instead of just calling a PACIFIC function because in the future i want to use the same function with different callback.

thnx !!!

Comment: I think Start activityforResult and onActivityResult can help you.

Comment: plz refer http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Wouldn't wanna mess with the pacific :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another ways can be to use `Handler` or `Interfaces`. For using handler, checkout [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13954718/1306419) by @FoamyGuy. You can extend his code to pass strings or whatever you want. Something like:

Pass in handler from where you are calling the method.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        if(msg.what == 1){
           //Success
           String msg = (String)msg.obj;
           Log.d("", "Msg is:"+msg);
        }else{
           //Failure
           String msg = (String)msg.obj;
           Log.d("", "Msg is:"+msg);    
        }
    }
};

loadToastMD.doEvent(toastModel, handler);
```

Send the message back based on whatever happened there:

```
public void doEvent(LoadToast toastModel, Handler handler) {
    ....
    public void onFinish() {
       ****DO THE CALLBACK HERE
       ****DO THE CALLBACK HERE
       Message m = handler.obtainMessage(1, "Success finish message string");
       m.sendToTarget();
    }
}
```