# Store and restore RecyclerView position not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll-position

I am using GridLayoutManager as LayoutManager for RecyclerView inside a fragment , and RecyclerView adapter get populated by loader.
I tried to store and restore state of GridLayoutManager on device rotation but not working and still get back to the initial state "first element in RecyclerView".

onSaveInstanceState method:

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    mRecylcerViewParecelable = mGridView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    outState.putParcelable(GRID_LAYOUT_PARCEL_KEY, mRecylcerViewParecelable);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

onViewStateRestored method:

```
    @Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        mRecylcerViewParecelable = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(GRID_LAYOUT_PARCEL_KEY);
    }
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
}
```

onLoadFinished method:

```
    @Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mMovieAdapter.swapCursor(data);
  mGridView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(mRecylcerViewParecelable);}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap `onRestoreInstanceState()` inside Handler:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                mGridView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(listState);
            }
        }, 300);
```

It's a hack to delay the `onRestoreInstanceState`.
I've experienced the same issue, IMO it looks like the RecyclerView keeps going back to initial state because the data in Adapter still being populated when we call the `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Comment: Nice one - this small addition of a delay resolved my issue (with a recyclerview in a fragment) with an adaptor containing a large number of records.

Comment: In general you must restore after you set the data

Comment: Why do we need `Handler`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky there's a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13954718/4447757
and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921759/4447757, and here in Android dev: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler
Basically you need to wrap the Runnable with Handler

Comment: It is only for cross-thread and cross-context.  For everything else, use Kotlin Coroutines.