# How use toast in a thread?

Tags: android, toast

how I can use toast inside of a thread? sorry for my english

Toast.makeText(this, "Show Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

this not work? I am new in android.

Lo siento por mi ingles, es muy malo.

Comment: ok sorry, but I try all from this 2 links you send but not work for me.

Comment: If you have tried those and they didn't work then you should mention that in your post along with adding the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calling an Activity's runOnUiThread method from your thread:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3134720/1121804)

Comment: All you did was copy/paste another answer

Comment: that's correct.  and cited it

Comment: you should flag is as duplicate instead of copy it

Comment: Right, and that is good that you cited but if you aren't going to add any extra info then it's better just to close as a dupe

Comment: yeah I just put it here in case it didn't get accepted as a dupe, at least he would have an answer.  I'll flag it next time