# Toast is not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley, android-alertdialog

> I am using volley for network call

---

Toast in volley request is not showing. I don't get how to get context in alert dialog from fragment . So please give solution of how i can print toast in volley response.

```
public class TiffinMenuFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tiffinlayout, null);
    alertdialog.setView(v);
    alertdialog.setCancelable(false);


    final AlertDialog dialog = alertdialog.create();

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            String type=selectmenu.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Log.v("java1",type);


            String url_menu=UrlString.url_string;
            url_menu = url_menu.replace(" ", "%20");
            Log.v("url",url_menu);
            final StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url_menu, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.v("Response",response);
                    JSONObject obj= null;
                    try {
                        obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        String objResponse=obj.getString("success");
                        Log.v("Response1",objResponse);
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Task is Completed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.v("type",error.getMessage());
                }
            });
            MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).addToRequestque(stringRequest);
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    cancle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });




    return dialog;

}
}
```

Comment: here is [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread)

Comment: Are you getting log message for response?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: set `getActivity()` instead of `view.getContext()`

Comment: Yes I m getting log message @Mohammed Atif

Comment: getActivity() is not working.

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Text!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should always add a explanation to it explaining why/how the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You context your using in Toast that is not correct use below one

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Task is Completed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: where are you using TiffinMenuFragment ??

Comment: i m calling this fragment from one of the custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
                Toast.makeText(dialog.getContext(),"Task is Completed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Use this.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Task is
Completed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Toast.makeText(dialog.getActivity(),"Task is Completed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43230652/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score -1):

You cant touch the UI from background thread

To show toast use this code

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

or the request getting failed and not calling that **onResponse** function.

Comment: this thing is a background process which is also thread final StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url_menu, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {}

Comment: background operations are normally called thread and it cant touch the UI . For that you need to use the above code . Please try to learn some base classes that would be helpful for you.