# How to display a toast message by clicking on a homescreen widget in android studio?

Tags: java, android

please tell me what i'm doing wrong

```
NewAppWidget.java class

package com.example.kinjolnath.alert;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */

public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static final String TAG = NewAppWidget.class.getSimpleName();

void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Inside updateAppWidget");
    Log.i(TAG, "Inside updateAppWidget");
    Log.e(TAG, "Inside updateAppWidget");


//        Toast.makeText(context,
//                "Should appear at widget click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton, pendingIntent);
    Intent sendingIntent = new Intent(context, SendingService.class);
    sendingIntent.setAction(SendingService.ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE);
    PendingIntent sendingPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, sendingIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton, sendingPendingIntent);
    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}


@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    Log.d(TAG, "Inside onUpdate");
    Log.i(TAG, "Inside onUpdate");
    Log.e(TAG, "Inside onUpdate");
    SendingService.startActionSendMessage(context);
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    Log.d(TAG, "Inside onEnabled");
    Log.i(TAG, "Inside onEnabled");
    Log.e(TAG, "Inside onEnabled");
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    Log.d(TAG, "Inside onDisabled");
    Log.i(TAG, "Inside onDisabled");
    Log.e(TAG, "Inside onDisabled");
    }
}
```

SendingService.java class

```
package com.example.kinjolnath.alert;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by kinjolnath on 01-06-2017.
 */

public class SendingService extends IntentService{
    private static final String TAG = NewAppWidget.class.getSimpleName();
    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
 * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
 */
public static final String ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE = "com.example.MapsActivity.action.send_message";

public SendingService(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public static void startActionSendMessage(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SendingService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE);
    context.startService(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "Inside startActionSendMessage");
    Log.i(TAG, "Inside startActionSendMessage");
    Log.e(TAG, "Inside startActionSendMessage");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null){
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, action + "inside onHandleIntent");
        if(ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE.equals(action)){
            handleActionSend();
        }
    }
}
//handleActionSend method:
private void handleActionSend() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "Inside handleActionSend");
    Log.i(TAG, "Inside handleActionSend");
    Log.e(TAG, "Inside handleActionSend");
    }
}
```

I followed a tutorial from Udacity and ended up at this stage but it still doesn't work
I am new to android development so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are your logs working everywhere? That is, is the `Toast` the only thing that's not working?

Comment: Toast is commented for your code.

Comment: @MikeM. the logs in handleActionSend is not working

Comment: @santoshkumar the toast is in the handleActionSend method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not show Toast on Clicking of WidGet because the widget extends **AppWidgetProvider** so that class not able to call **current Context**

If you want to show Toast when create widget or select widget is possible by using bellow code:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context,"hiii dhruv", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

==========================================================================

How to user above code in your widget class

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(final Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context,"hiii dhruv", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

====================================================================

or

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Toast.makeText(context, "hiiiiiiiiiiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: The link you provided helped a lot. I did an override on the onRecieve method and now it works. thanks

Comment: @kinjol yes you are right if you like my code then please right mark on it
thank you

Answer (score -1):

Please see this: [Android: Toast in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread)

If toast is not showing then its probably not using the UI thread. You can try using applicationContext instead of this, though I'm not sure that will work. I don't like to run Toasts when the UI isn't visible but have run across this to use for specific testing without having to look at logs.