# Toast from JobIntentService

Tags: android-handler, android-toast, android-looper, jobintentservice

I am a beginner.
I want Toast from jobintentservice (onHandleWork) but crash my app.
logcat error is : " can't toast on a thread that has not called looper.prepare()"
i want learn work with handler in jobintentservice
please help me.

```
public class NotificationService extends JobIntentService {
    public static final String TAG = NotificationService.class.getSimpleName();
    Handler handler;

    public static void enqueuWork(Context context,Intent intent){
        enqueueWork(context,NotificationService.class,20,intent);
    }
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Start background Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handler = new Handler();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run()
              Toast.makeText(NotificationService.this, "onhandlework", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

you probebly figured it out by now, but for future readers, the error "can't toast on a thread that has not called looper.prepare()" simply means you must call ui related from ui thread.

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    showToast(activity);
}});
```

you can find similiar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)