# Android thread in service issue

Tags: android

I am having a remote service running in which i am spawning a new thread to keep polling for incoming messages via socket and then at certain intervals i want to stop the socket and restart later...stopping is working fine (stopUARTConnection()) but re starting(startUARTConnection) is not causing the while loop again.. Can someone tell me whats wrong ?

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service{

ServerSocket server = null;
Socket socketClient = null;
InputStream is = null;
BufferedReader br = null;
char[] buff = null;
boolean threadRunning = true;

private static final String TAG = BackgroundService.class.getSimpleName();
private Thread socketThread = null;
int temp = 0;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (BackgroundService.class.getName().equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Bound by intent " + intent);
        return apiEndpoint;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private final Object latestIncomingMessage = new Object();
private List<MessageCollectorListener> listeners = new ArrayList<MessageCollectorListener>();
private Message message = new Message(" ");

private MessageCollectorApi.Stub apiEndpoint = new MessageCollectorApi.Stub() {
    @Override
    public void removeListener(MessageCollectorListener listener) throws RemoteException {
        synchronized (listener) {
            listeners.remove(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Message getValue() throws RemoteException {
        synchronized (latestIncomingMessage) {
            return message;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(MessageCollectorListener listener) throws RemoteException {
        synchronized (listener) {
            listeners.add(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startBroadCastConn() throws RemoteException {
        try {
            startUARTConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("B Service", "Stop UART CONNECTION");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void stopBroadCastConn() throws RemoteException {
        try {
            stopUARTConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("B Service", "Stop UART CONNECTION");
        }           
    }
};

public boolean createSocket(int port) {
    try{
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean listenSocket(){
    try{
        socketClient = server.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    socketThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(threadRunning){
                boolean socketCreated = createSocket(8080);
                boolean socketListen = listenSocket();
                if(socketListen == true && socketCreated == true){
                    //To add code for processing data..
                    threadRunning = true;
                }
                try {
                    recycle();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }   
    };
    socketThread.start();
}
public void stopUARTConnection() throws IOException{
    recycle();
    threadRunning = false;
}

public void startUARTConnection() throws IOException{
    recycle();
    threadRunning = true;
}

private void recycle() throws IOException{
    if(socketClient != null){
        socketClient.close();
        socketClient = null;
    }   
    if(is != null)
        is.close();
    if(server != null){
        server.close();
        server = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        recycle();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("B Service", "Failed to recycle all values");
    }
    socketThread = null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the Thread only once. The loop is thus run only once until it is instructed to exit.

```
public void startUARTConnection() throws IOException{
    recycle();
    socketThread = new SocketThread();
    socketThread.start();
}

public void stopUARTConnection() throws IOException{
    recycle();
    socketThread = null;
}

private class SocketThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Loop until socketThread is assigned something else 
        // (a new Thread instance or simply null)
        while (socketThread==this){
            boolean socketCreated = createSocket(8080);
            boolean socketListen = listenSocket();
            if(socketListen == true && socketCreated == true){
                // To add code for processing data..
            }
            try {
                recycle();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }   
};
```

Comment: hmmm... looks right...but should nt we destroy the thread before starting again...should i just assign the thread to null to do it?

Comment: `socketThread==this` will detect that you have created a new SocketThread and the old Thread will then exit. If you need to be sure you don't have 2 threads running at the same time, you'll need to implement a check based on `join()`.

Comment: Hey....thanks a  lot...your solution was right..thanks a lot..really new to threads... :)

Comment: @Arun Abraham: If Marvin has solved your problem, you really should accept the answer...

Answer (score 0):

When you call stopUARTConnection, you're setting threadRunning=false... at this point, your while loop is exiting... in startUARTConnection, you're setting threadRunning to true, but you're not restarting the thread.

As @Marvin has pointed out, [you can't just call start on the thread object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215548/is-it-legal-to-call-the-start-method-twice-on-the-same-thread), you need to recreate it.

Comment: -1 because you cannot start a Thread that has already been started once. Will throw IllegalThreadStateException the second time startUARTConnection is called.

Comment: hear i have to destroy that thread before doing start again..can we destroy by just assigning the thread = null; ???

Comment: @Arun Abraham: see Marvin's response.  You shouldn't have to destroy the thread (it will have exited), you can create a new one over the existing reference

Comment: @MarvinLabs: Thanks for the pointer.  I wasn't aware that you couldn't restart a threadobject, I assumed one it entered an exit-state it would be ok.  I guess it's not something I've ever needed to do, typically if I start a thread I'm not expecting to shut it down until the application is ready to exit.

Comment: Always explicitly shutdown the threads you start, else they will just keep running in the background and you'll leak memory...

Comment: @MarvinLabs: Doesn't it shutdown once it exits the run method?

Comment: It does shutdown **if** it exits the run method (lots of people have a loop that will not exit on its own but needs to be told to exit explicitly)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) instead of thread/while and [ConditionVariable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ConditionVariable.html) instead boolean variable `threadRunning`