# Java - Running a thread twice

Tags: java, multithreading

[From another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1215553/632951):

> If a Thread needs to be run more than once, then one should make an
>   new instance of the Thread and call start on it.

How is this done?

Comment: Check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: How do you create an instance of a thread and run it the first time?

Comment: http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html

Comment: Martin would say 'if you want a thread to run twice, put a for loop around all the existing code in the thread function'.

Comment: each thread just run its `Runnable`, and doesn't care if it's as same as other, because each thread has its private stack. for example check [this example](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#rccig)

Comment: check this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215548/is-it-legal-to-call-the-start-method-twice-on-the-same-thread)

Answer (score 6):

I would use another layer of abstraction. Use an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Here is a simple example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    final ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    final class MyTask implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Running my task.");
        }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        service.submit(new MyTask());
    }
    service.shutdown();
    service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
}
```

Just dump your task into the `service` as many times as you want.

The `ExecutorService` is a thread pool - it has a number of `Thread`s that take tasks as they come. This removes the overhead of spawning new `Thread`s because it caches them.

Comment: Although this answer seems to be a little bit off-topic to me, I appreciate every statement that explains the ExecutorService and favours it over usual "Threading" as still there are much too few people knowing the new fancy concurrency API. +1!

Answer (score 3):

Basically, a thread cannot be restarted.

So if you want a reusable "thread", you are really talking about a `Runnable`.  You might do something like this:

```
  Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          // Do some task
      }
  }

  Thread t1 = new Thread(myTask);
  t1.start();
  t1.join();
  Thread t2 = new Thread(myTask);
  t2.start();
```

(This is purely for illustration purposes only!  It is much better to run your "runnables" using a more sophisticated mechanism, such as provided by one of the `ExecutorService` classes, which is going to manage the actual threads in a way that avoids them terminating.)

Answer (score 2):

A java `Thread` cannot be run twice. Once it has been started and finished its work, it cannot be started again (calling method `start` will fail). So you'll have to create a new instance of `Thread` (using the same `Runnable`) and start it.

Comment: Did you even read the description or did you only read the title ? I said i didn't understand what this ment ...

Comment: What did you not understand? I explained that you have to create a new instance of Thread and start it. Its not more nor less than that. Do you really want me to write down this two lines of code?