# Second time running the thread makes application crash

Tags: android, multithreading

I use a worker thread to read text from a url. My thread is as follow. In the first time running, I am sure thread running is finished as I can check `sdcard_readstr` is `null`.
In the second time running, when I call `thread_download.start();`, then the program crashed.
What could be wrong? Thanks

```
public class DownloadingThread extends AbstractDataDownloading {


      @Override
      public void doRun() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
                // Create a URL for the desired page
                URL url = new URL(SDcard_DetailView.textfileurl);

                    // Read all the text returned by the server
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new  
                    InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

                do{
                     sdcard_readstr = in.readLine();
                }while(sdcard_readstr!=null);
                in.close();

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}


public abstract  class AbstractDataDownloading extends Thread{
       private final Set<ThreadCompleteListener> listeners
          = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<ThreadCompleteListener>();
       public final void addListener(final ThreadCompleteListener listener) {
            listeners.add(listener);
       }
       public final void removeListener(final ThreadCompleteListener listener) {
            listeners.remove(listener);
       }
       private final void notifyListeners() {
           for (ThreadCompleteListener listener : listeners) {
                 listener.notifyOfThreadComplete(this);
           }
       }
       @Override
       public final void run() {
          try {
                 doRun();
          } finally {
                 notifyListeners();
          }
       }
      public abstract void doRun();


}
```

EDIT1:
In my thread complete notification, I use `runOnUiThread`to use the UI components.
Is that causing problem?

```
public void notifyOfThreadComplete(Thread thread) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(downloadingStopbuttonispressed == false){//background process completed

            textfileurl = null;

            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Wifibutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Wifiscanning); 
                    Wifibutton.setText("Load another day's data");
                    final MenuItem refreshItem = optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.airport_menuRefresh);
                    refreshItem.setActionView(null);
                }
            });


        }
    }
```

I called thread start in onResume() as

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(textfileurl != null){
            Wifibutton.setText("Stop Data Loading");
            buttonStatus = "loading";           
            setRefreshActionButtonState(true);          
            thread_download.start();            
        }
    }
```

EDIT2:
My LogCat image is attached.
[image]

Comment: why downvoted?pls give me reason. What is wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code when the DownloadingThread.start() being called?

Comment: @dieend, I have updated to my original post. I call thread start at onResume().

Comment: Please add exception stacktrace from logcat for the crash

Comment: @laalto; LogCat is attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215548/is-it-legal-to-call-the-start-method-twice-on-the-same-thread) . I can't reuse the same instance of the `Thread` object in the second time. I need to create a new instance to call the `Thread` in the second time. So Thread is suitable for single time running process, for multiple time running process I should use `AsyncTask`. Even `AsyncTack` is only for one time execution and for multiple time execution, we should use as `new MyAsyncTask().execute("");` I don't understand why people downvote with no reason given. I couldn't find the link in my first search.