# SwingWorker executed more than once by difference instances?

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

My question is can `SwingWorker`'s `doInBackground` method be executed more than once, by difference instances of the same class?

For example, there is a class called `ClientGUI` and there are 2 instances, `ClientGUI1` and `ClientGUI2`, will each of these instances be able to call the `doInBackground` method of `SwingWorker` at least once?

Answer (score 0):

No. But, what you can do is create a new instance of the SwingWorker, and then start those.

From the Java API specification:

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

Check out this SO question on threads:
[Is it legal to call the start method twice on the same Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215548/is-it-legal-to-call-the-start-method-twice-on-the-same-thread)