# Best practice for Threads manipullation and Thread destroy?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using `Thread`s (still..) for many stuff right now. I found many methods of thread that I would most likely use marked as deprecated.

Is there any chance to pause/resume thread with some triggers? Most people say to use wait.. but if I don't know the time ? I have some events that can happen after 5 minutes or after 2 hours...

Also .. another thing.

If I have a `Thread` .. it has an `run()` method. Now the Thread is started , run does what it has to do and then the `Thread` dies. Like forever ? The stuff from `run()` method is done so the Thread is ready to be taken out by garbage collector or is it just in some phase of disabled but still existing ?

Now you have a run method like that :

```
public void run(){
   while(running){
      //do stuff...
   }
}
```

If I switch the running to `false`, run method loops and stops because there is nothing more to do . Does this thread also die ? Can I for example say after some time I want to rerun this thread, so I just set the running to `true` again and call the run method, or do I have to recreate the `Thread` once again ?

Comment: For the first point, look for the Wait/Notify pattern http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/

Comment: For the second point : the thread will be taken out by garbage collector once not one has kept a reference on it (you may want to get some fields values). And you can't start a thread more than once : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215548/is-it-legal-to-call-the-start-method-twice-on-the-same-thread?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: _then the `Thread` dies.  Like forever?_  Yes.  Forever.  A `Thread` can only be started one time.

Comment: _run method [returns] because there is nothing more to do . Does this thread also die?_  Yes.  A thread dies when its `run()` method returns, or when an exception is thrown out of its `run()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Thread` can only "live" once. When you create a `Thread`, you specify a `Runnable` instance as a target (if you don't, the thread targets itself—it implements `Runnable` and its default `run()` method does nothing). In either case, when the thread completes the `run()` method of its target `Runnable`, the thread dies.

In the example posed in the question, setting `running` to `true` after the `run()` method has returned will do nothing; the `Thread` can't be restarted after dying.

If you want to pause a thread, and reuse it later, there are a number of mechanisms. The most primitive is `wait()` and `notify()`. Rather than waiting for a specified period of time, you wait until a condition changes, like this:

```
abstract class Pausable implements Runnable {

  private final Object lock = new Object();

  private boolean pause = false;

  abstract void doSomething();

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (cantering()) doSomething();
  }

  private boolean cantering() {
    synchronized (lock) {
      while (pause) {
        try { lock.wait(); }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) { 
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  final void whoa() {
    synchronized(lock) {
      pause = true;
    }
  }

  final void giddyup() {
    synchronized(lock) {
      pause = false;
      lock.notify();
    }
  }

}
```

That's a lot of code, and it's fragile. I've been writing Java for 20 years and I'm not sure I got it right. That's why you should use the right tool from `java.util.concurrency`. For example, if you are waking up the thread to process a message, use a `BlockingQueue`, and let the consuming thread wait for messages to arrive on the queue. If you have tasks you want to perform asynchronously in response to some event, create an `ExecutorService` and submit the tasks. Even if you do want to use something like `wait()/notify()`, the `concurrency` package's `Condition` class gives you a lot more control over locking than intrinsic locks offer.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I [...] and call the run method?

If you have a `Thread t = ...;`, and you write a call to `t.run()`, you probably are making a mistake.

A `Thread` is not a *thread*.  A *thread* is a path of execution through your code.  A `Thread` is an *object* with methods that can be used to create a new *thread* and manage its life-cycle.

You create the new *thread* by calling `t.start()`.

**Remember this mantra:**

The `start()` method is the method that the *library* provides for your code to call when you want to start a new thread.

The `run()` method is the method that *your code* provides for the library to call *in* the new thread.